# Why have "while(1);" in XmlHttpRequest response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

I'm playing firebug with Google Calendar. I happens to find that some XHR request has response like below:

```
while(1);[['us','bW9yZ2FuLmNoZW5nbW9AZ21haWwuY29t 20090320/20090904 63378122163']]
```

It looks like a JSON with prefix dead-loop javascript statements.

I'm not sure why Google Calendar has such kind of XHR response. Is there any known AJAX practice about this?