# Empty "for" loop in Facebook ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

While surfing facebook and using the Firebug network debugger I noticed that facebook's AJAX responses all start with an empty for loop.

Example:

```
for(;;);{...}
```

Does anyone know why this is done?  I assume it's to prevent some sort of XSS attack but I don't totally understand. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it tries to hang the JS engine if the response is eval'd.  Probably to make users of the Facebook API use their JSON-parsing library instead of eval?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like google's

```
while(1);
```

it done for preventing of including this in `<script>` with further using the data

Comment: can u plz explain a little bit more?

Comment: @zerkms : u means this to prevent XSS attack??

Comment: @zerkms : how `while(1);` will prevent including `while(1);`in `<script>` with further data?

Comment: @RSK The following may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-append-while1-in-front-of-their-json-responses

Comment: If included, it will hang the Javascript interpreter, so you will never get to use the data.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli and that's the whole idea