# How do I `jsonify` a list in Flask?

Tags: json, flask

Currently `Flask` would raise an error when jsonifying a list.

I know there could be security reasons https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/170, but I still would like to have a way to return a JSON list like the following:

```
[
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
]
```

instead of

```
{ 'results': [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
]}
```

on responding to a `application/json` request. How can I return a JSON list in Flask using Jsonify?

Comment: This is no longer a security issue, but it is still considered a best practice to always return a dict : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/304638/369319

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`jsonify` prevents you from doing this in Flask 0.10 and lower [for security reasons](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/security/#json-security).

To do it anyway, just use `json.dumps` in the Python standard library.

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps

Comment: Doing this, I will need to manually set the Content-Type of header as well?

Comment: Yes, `application/json`.

Comment: @FogleBird which security reason ?

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/security/#json-security

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the security reason. :D

Comment: Security is no longer a valid concern, so Flask's `jsonify` now supports dumping lists: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35000418/770425

Comment: The link @DavidRöthlisberger posted now 404s, but the information is in the 1.0 docs too: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/security/#json-security also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503102/557406

Answer (score 92):

You can't but you can do it anyway like this. I needed this for jQuery-File-Upload

```
import json
# get this object
from flask import Response

#example data:

    js = [ { "name" : filename, "size" : st.st_size , 
        "url" : url_for('show', filename=filename)} ]
#then do this
    return Response(json.dumps(js),  mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: There is also flask.json.dumps don't know if this is better than json.dumps

Comment: @CameronWhite - `flask.json` is shorthand for `try: import simplejson as json; except ImportError: import json`

Comment: +1 for mimetype='application/json', saved me looking for the relevant header :)

Comment: The funny thing is i was stuck on this in the exact same situation (jQuery File Upload) and your code helped me in another way as well.

Comment: I like this answer best. From my experience, `Response()` exposes mimetype in a simpler fashion than `make_response()` and just doing `return json.dumps()` doesn't set any headers.

Answer (score 25):

This is working for me. Which version of Flask are you using?

```
from flask import jsonify

...

@app.route('/test/json')
def test_json():
    list = [
            {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
            {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
           ]
    return jsonify(results = list)
```

Comment: Well I am using Flask 0.9 but it seems this would output a hash json rather than a list json.

Comment: recommending against using `list` as identifier of a variable

Answer (score 13):

Flask's `jsonify()` method now serializes top-level arrays as of [this commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/commit/431db2874b242316051963d9bc4d5653b3647acc), available in Flask 0.11 onwards.

For convenience, you can either pass in a Python list: `jsonify([1,2,3])`
Or pass in a series of `args`: `jsonify(1,2,3)`

Both will be serialized to a JSON top-level array: `[1,2,3]`

Details here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=jsonify#flask.json.jsonify**

Answer (score 7):

Solved, no fuss. You can be lazy and use jsonify, all you need to do is pass in items=[your list].

Take a look here for the solution

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/510

Answer (score 5):

A list in a flask can be easily jsonify using **jsonify** like:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'task':'this is first task'
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'task':'this is another task'
    }
]

@app.route('/app-name/api/v0.1/tasks',methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks':tasks})  #will return the json

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: `jsonify({'tasks': tasks})` Worked perfectly this has definitely saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

josonify works... But if you intend to just pass an array without the 'results' key, you can use JSON library from python. The following conversion works for me.

```
import json

@app.route('/test/json')
def test_json():
    mylist = [
        {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
        ]
    return json.dumps(mylist)
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, is the only that returns the correct data structure. Thansk a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching literally the way to return a **JSON list** in flask and you are completly sure that your variable is a list then the easy way is (where *bin* is a list of 1's and 0's):

```
   return jsonify({'ans':bin}), 201
```

Finally, in your client you will obtain something like

{ "ans": [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ] }