# List returned from python to Ajax get strange characters

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

How do I return a list correctly from Python to Ajax, the output looks strange when returned.

ap.py

```
@app.route('/_get_comUpdate/', methods=['POST'])
def _get_comUpdate():
    comNr = request.form.get('comNr')
        
    com_result = COMPort("ON","COM255",comNr)
    print(com_result)

    return jsonify({'data': render_template('com_response.html', com_result = com_result)})
```

com_response.html

```
{{com_result}}
```

index.html

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/_get_comUpdate/",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(resp){
        com_result = (resp.data);
        alert(com_result); 
        }
    });
```

Ouput of list in python:

```
['ON', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF']
```

Output of list returned to Ajax:

```
[&#39;ON&#39;, &#39;OFF&#39;, &#39;OFF&#39;, &#39;OFF&#39;, &#39;OFF&#39;, &#39;OFF&#39;]
```

Comment: instead of `request.form.get` have you tried `request.form.getlist`?

Comment: You are sending the array through the com_response.html, which you haven't posted, so it's tough to give a definitive answer, but it's probably in there somewhere.  i've used more Django than flask, but I'm guessing it's escaping things in there.  I expect there's some filters or flags you can use to mark it as safe so it doesn't escape.

Comment: Check it helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435297/how-do-i-jsonify-a-list-in-flask

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the possibly inaccurate recipe, because I can't see the all your code. I guess that the reason is in specifying the UTF-8 encoding

May be backend..

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api
from flask.ext.restful.representations.json import output_json
output_json.func_globals['settings'] = {'ensure_ascii': False, 'encoding': 'utf8'}
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
...
```

may be frontend

```
<html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8">
```

may be run application

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

And, can u use **json.dumps** instead **jsonify**? hope helped to you)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be some kind of  encoding problem. I will continue to investigate. =)

Comment: Try displaying the result on a list, for example ['your result']. Then it will be more obvious that it is UTF-8 or latinic. Sorry, a dont know, how say  about re-re-utf8

Comment: these moments are evident in IDE

Comment: I'm not even sure it is possible to return a list this way so I returned a comma separated string and split it into a array in the javascript.