# how to send string array as a response to ajax call from servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I made a ajax call from my jsp to servlet. when I want to return string then it is working fine. But I want to send response as a String array then its not working. Is it possible that I can send string array from servlet as a ajax response.

```
  String[] roleAccess=null; 
              response.setContentType("text/html");
                         try{
                            roleAccess=new String[23];
                            roleAccess[0]="";
                            roleAccess[1]="checked";
                            roleAccess[2]="";

 response.getWriter().write(roleAccess.toString());---this part I need to change.
```

Comment: Send the ajax response in json format. http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

Write it out to JSON instead.  Javascript can't understand the result of a Java array's toString() method (`[Ljava.lang.String;@5527f4f9`), but I know it can understand JSON.

If you're only ever going to be using a string array and you don't want to use any more libraries:

```
public static String toJSON(String[] array)
{
    String json = "[\"";

    for (String s : array)
    {
        json += s + "\",\"";
    }

    return json.substring(0, json.length() - 2) + "]";
}
```

Depending on what Javascript framework you're using on your client-side, your JSON will be available as the `xmlHttpRequestObject.responseText`.  AngularJS stores it in the `$http.get().success` method's first `data` parameter.  jQuery stores it in the `$.ajax({success})` method's first `data` parameter.  Angular and jQuery automatically validate and `eval` it to an `[object Object]` for you, but `xmlHttpRequestObject.responseText` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Send the ajax response in [json](http://www.json.org/) format by encoding the array in json and return it.

You can use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and then encode your array like:

```
String jsonRoleAccess = new Gson().toJson(roleAccess, roleAccess.class);
response.getWriter().write(jsonRoleAccess);

// OR do a one liner:
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(roleAccess, roleAccess.class));
```

And on the Javascript end, you can access it as a json object

```
// Assuming you've read the ajax response into var roleAccess
var checked = roleAccess[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to marshall the array as a JSON data type.  The format returned by Java's array class is not in a format that JavaScript understands.

You should also wrap your array inside of an Object because of a security issue of passing top-level arrays back as JSON.

See [Why are top level json arrays a security risk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503102/what-are-top-level-json-arrays-and-why-are-they-a-security-risk)