# Change way of array serialization in jms

Tags: symfony, gson, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

When I'm seralize array I've got something like this:

```
{"0":{"id":1,"name":"Kowalscy","familyMembers":[{"id":1,"familyMemberType":1,"user":{},"name":"Pawel","isAdmin":true,"notes":[],"email":""},{"id":2,"familyMemberType":2,"user":{},"name":"Mama Koper","isAdmin":false,"notes":[],"email":""}],"children":[]},
"1":{"id":2,"name":"Spiochy","familyMembers":[{"id":3,"familyMemberType":2,"user":{},"name":"Test Nowak","isAdmin":false,"notes":[],"email":""}],"children":[]}, .....
```

But I have problem with deseralization that array using JSON, I think that it should look like:

```
[{object}, {object}]
```

Is there way to change that?

Here is my code from symfony2

```
$result = $serializer->serialize($families, 'json',SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('getFamilies')));
```

EDIT:
I've found that "getArrayResult()" returns array, but it doesn't contain my relation entity

Comment: is $families an array of entities having a relation with another entity?

Comment: Yes, I've got it from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, it is a bad practice to have an array as top level in json.

[What are "top level JSON arrays" and why are they a security risk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503102/what-are-top-level-json-arrays-and-why-are-they-a-security-risk)

Moreother, if you use array, you lost the ids of your objects. So it is normal that you lost relations.

Comment: Thank you, I've packed my JSON array with object :)