# Jersey subresource wraps my API in an extra layer of JSON - why would I want this?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

As an illustration, let's suppose I'm creating an HTTP REST API that behaves as follows:

Return a collection of all employees:

```
GET /employees/

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "responsibility": 1000
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Return a representation of employee with id 1:

```
GET /employees/1/

{
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "responsibility": 1000
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Return a collection of the employee's roles:

```
GET /employees/1/roles

[
    {
        "id": 20,
        "responsibility": 1000
    },
    ...
]
```

Return a representation of role with id 20:

```
GET /employees/1/roles/20

{
    "id": 20,
    "responsibility": 1000
}
```

In this way we can traverse the tree of the employee representation. There are likely many other employee endpoints besides /roles.

Using Jersey I split this up into a root resource with several subresources, for example:

```
@Path("/employees")
public class EmployeesResource() {
    ...
    @GET
    @Path("/{employeeId}/roles")
    public RolesResource getRoles(@PathParam("employeeId") long employeeId) {
        return new RolesResource(employeeId);
    }
}
```

This produces the desired JSON result when I GET `/employees` and `/employees/1` but when I GET `/employees/1/roles` I get the response body:

```
{
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 20,
            "responsibility": 1000
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Jersey has wrapped my collection of Role representations in some object. Note: The object seems to be connected to the name of the subresource resource method within RolesResource (for example, if the method is named `getRoles()` I get `{"roles": [...]}`, if the method is named `getFoo()` I get `{"foo": [...]}`).

**My Question:** There must be a reason Jersey does this. Why would I want my representation to be wrapped like this? And if there isn't a good reason, how can I get rid of this?

Edit: I'm using Dropwizard version 0.8.2, which it looks like [from maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-jersey/0.8.2) is pulling in Jersey 2.19. It uses Jackson as the JSON provider - again, from maven it looks like the version is 2.5.1. No web.xml as this is a dropwizard application.

Comment: Returning the top-level value as an array is a security vulnerability.  That's why Jersey won't do it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503102/what-are-top-level-json-arrays-and-why-are-they-a-security-risk

Comment: That's interesting, I'd never heard about that vulnerability before. Isn't it pretty common for REST endpoints to serve top-level arrays? For example, https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/3fecge/.json. Also, Jersey does serve a top-level array from the EmployeesResource at `/employees/`, it just wraps any subresources. That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had annotated the subresource locator (`EmployeesResource.getRoles()` in this example) with `@GET`. Removing that annotation produced the desired result. The methods within RolesResource are annotated with HTTP method names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `dropwizard` but I do know `jackson` and I'm currently using jersey 2.21, so I hope my setup is closed enough to yours.

I guess you have constructed your `RolesResource` class somewhat similar to this (if it is not the case, please post it!)

```
public class RolesResource {
    private Role[] roles;

    //constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

where `Role` would be something like,

```
public class Role {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer responsibility;

    //constructor, getters, setters...
}
```

If this is the case, if you return `RolesResource` as an output of your service, you will just get the `json` you describe,

```
{
    "roles": [
        {
           ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

since the object has actually an array `Role[]` with name `roles`.

However, you could also return `Role[]` as an output of your service,

```
@Path("/employees")
public class EmployeesResource() {
    ...
    @GET
    @Path("/{employeeId}/roles")
    public Role[] getRoles(@PathParam("employeeId") long employeeId) {
        return (new RolesResource(employeeId)).getRoles();
    }
}
```

And then the output will be just array of objects of type `Role`.

```
[
    {
        "id": ...,
        "responsibility": ...
    },
    ...
]
```

As for your question, does either make more sense than the other? I guess it is a matter of choice; I usually prefer to encapsulate so that it is easier to check on the client side (thus I go for the first solution), but I don't think it makes a big difference.

Hope it helps.