# Django/Ajax/Javasdript JSON.parse convert string to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, django, model

I am using Ajax to to send a get request from the sever, i am querying and getting a particular product from the product model, i want to return result as JavaScript objects but its return this '{' as i try to access the first value from the responseText[0]. How can i convert data return to js object.
here is my code

views.py

```
def edit_product(request):
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    print('THIS IS PRODUCT ID ', product_id)
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    data = [
    {
        'name':product.name,
        'brand':product.brand,
        'price':product.price,
        'description':product.description 

    }
]
return HttpResponse(data)
```

ajax.js

```
function getProductEditId(product_id){
            //alert(id)

document.getElementById('gridSystemModalLabel').innerHTML='<b> Edit product </b>';
            //change modal header from Add product to  Edit product
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', '/edit_product/?product_id=' + product_id, true);
            request.onload = function(){
                console.log('hello world', product_id)
                //var data = request.responseText
                var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request.responseText));
                console.log(data[0])

            }
            request.send();

        }
```

Comment: get rid of `JSON.stringify` - i expect `request.responseText` is already a `JSON`

Comment: **Do not send your JSON data in a list `[...]`** It's known to be [insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3503102/1925257). Send it in a dict `{...}`.

Comment: @xyres the JSON array vulnerability [was fixed ages ago](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/why-json-hijacking-attack-doesnt-work-in-modern-browsers-how-was-it-fixed)

Comment: `JSON.parse(request.responseText)` should work

Comment: @ic3b3rg I'd err on the side of caution, for a user might be running an old browser. Interestingly, I've also never come across a third-party API that sends JSON data in an array.

Comment: @xyres that issue affected FF 1.5 and 2b - *no one* is using those browsers - claiming JSON arrays are a security vulnerability is FUD - I use JSON arrays all the time

Comment: JSON.parse(request.responseText)    does not work here is the error i get             VM4496:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTTP response can not contain a dictionary, you can pass data through a specific format, like for example JSON. Django offers some convenience for that with the [**`JsonResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def edit_product(request):
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    print('THIS IS PRODUCT ID ', product_id)
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    data = [
        {
            'name':product.name,
            'brand':product.brand,
            'price':product.price,
            'description':product.description 
        }
    ]
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

But as the code hints, this is not safe, since an array at the root level was a famous [JSON hijacking exploit](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/).

It is typically better to just pass a dictionary (so no list), and then the `safe=False` parameter can be removed. Although it is not really "safe" to then just assume that all security exploits are gone.

Alternatively, you can use [**`json.dumps`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.dumps) (which is more or less what `JsonResponse` does internally), but then you thus will probably end with duplicate code.

At the JavaScript side, you then only need to *parse* the JSON blob to a JavaScript object:

```
//change modal header from Add product to  Edit product
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/edit_product/?product_id=' + product_id, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log('hello world', product_id)
    if(this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(data[0])
    }
}
```

It is also not very clear to me why you encapsulate the data in a list here: if the response always contains one element, it makes more sense to just pass the dictionary.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that `JsonResponse` won't convert `data` to JSON if it's not a dict (unless it is given `safe=False` parameter). Otherwise it will raise error.

Comment: @xyres: well a problem with the `safe` parameter, is that it gives a false impression that the data is safe then. But it is not said that other exploits could not eventually redefine the root `Object` call. Google for example uses `while(1);` at the top of a JSON to "trick" malicious scripts in getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Using a list because i want to be able access the data in javascript objects like this  data[0].name, if i use just a dict calling that same code return undefine , so please if there a better way i can avoid this list it will be fine .

Comment: Thanks everyone i finally got it right i remove  the list and contain my data in a dict. To access data i just use data.name and it works. Thanks once again