# Why is it bad to use non-dict objects in JsonResponse?

Tags: python, json, django

By default Django's `JsonResponse` class doesn't allow non-dict objects like arrays. I've looked at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) but it never explains why that'd be unsafe or otherwise undesired.

Are there any good reasons only to use dict objects? I found something about [old security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503102/what-are-top-level-json-arrays-and-why-are-they-a-security-risk) but as far as I can tell that's all patched up now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's just non standard. JSON is JavaScript *Object* Notation, so it's expected of JSON responses to be well, JavaScript objects. Most HTTP libraries would expect an object out of a `Content-Type: json` response, and might fail to parse your array response depending on the implementation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "object" in the name is meant more generically, rather than the referring specifically to the set of key/value pairs also called an object.

Comment: Is there an official spec for this? Because the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types_and_syntax) does mention arrays as one of the JSON data types.

Comment: I found [the relevant RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) and arrays are an officially supported type.