# Is there a way to call a variable that is been declared in within a foreach function block?

Tags: c#

For Instance

```
List<BursaryPaymentSplitting> splitAccount = new List<BursaryPaymentSplitting>();

foreach ( var lineItem in splitAccount)
{
    var lineItems = new RemitaSplit { 
        lineItemsId = lineItem.BursaryPaymentSplittingId.ToString(), 
        beneficiaryName = lineItem.AccountName, 
        beneficiaryAccount = lineItem.AccountNumber, 
        bankCode = lineItem.BankCode, 
        beneficiaryAmount = lineItem.Amount.ToString(), 
        deductFeeFrom = lineItem.DeductFeeFrom.ToString() 
    };
}
```

How do i make use of the variable `lineItems` outside the `foreach` function block

Comment: You can't. If you want to use the new objects, use `Select` instead and loop over them

Comment: You can only use the variable if you declare it outside the foreach. Such as: `RemitaSplit lineItems  = null;`. After the foreach check for `null` to see if the variable now holds a (valid) value.

Comment: `lineItems` is a single `RemitaSplit` instance. What do you want to do with it? It doesn't have any meaning outside the loop anyway - even if you put it outside the loop, it will only hold the last loop value once the  loop finishes.

Comment: if you made a class or structure you could store the line items details in a list and access the processed results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineItems` changes throughout the `foreach`.

Let's examine the code.

```
foreach ( var lineItem in splitAccount)
{
    var lineItems = new RemitaSplit {
```

This translates to something like this: For each element in `splitAccount` create a new single reference called `lineItems` and assign a new `RemitaSplit` object to it. The type of `lineItems` will be `RemitaSplit`, it will not be `List<RemitaSplit>`.

## Solution

I suspect you need something like the following.

```
using System.Linq;

(...)

var lineItems = splitAccount.Select( lineItem =>  new RemitaSplit { ... } ).ToList();
```

## with `foreach`

```
var lineItems = new List<RemitaSplit>();
foreach ( var lineItem in splitAccount)
{
   //item, not items
   var lineItem = new RemitaSplit { 
       lineItemsId = lineItem.BursaryPaymentSplittingId.ToString(),
       (...)
   };
   lineItems.Add(lineItem);
}
```

---

## Edit: json

> My objective is to serialize the lineItems and post as json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; 
using System.Linq;

(...)

var lineItems = splitAccount.Select( lineItem => 
    new RemitaSplit { 
        lineItemsId = lineItem.BursaryPaymentSplittingId.ToString(), 
        (...)
        }).ToList();

// Wrapping in an object, as an example, 
// the web doesn't like top level json arrays
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503102/what-are-top-level-json-arrays-and-why-are-they-a-security-risk
// but what you send will be guided by the api the json is sent to. 
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { Items = lineItems });
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The Object `lineItems` will hold all the records gotten from the `splitAccount`. My objective is to serialize the `lineItems` and post as json to a url and i can't do that right in the `foreach`code block function.

Comment: @Brainiac005 it's a single `RemitaSplit` entry, not multiple line items. Do you want to serialize that single entry or all the RemitaSplit entries?

Comment: `var lineItems = splitAccount.Select( lineItem =>  new RemitaSplit { ... } ).ToList();` This worked

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable in the scope that you need it.  For example:

```
RemitaSplit lineItems;
foreach (var lineItem in splitAccount)
{
    lineItems = new RemitaSplit { /.../ };
}
// Here you can access the lineItems variable.
// Though it *might* be NULL, your code should account for that.
```

Though what's strange here is that you're overwriting the same variable over and over.  Why?  Did you mean to have a *collection* of objects instead of just one object?  Something like this?:

```
var lineItems = new List<RemitaSplit>();
foreach (var lineItem in splitAccount)
{
    lineItems.Add(new RemitaSplit { /.../ });
}
// Here you can access the lineItems variable.
// And this time it won't be NULL, though it may be an empty collection.
```

Which could potentially be simplified to:

```
var lineItems = splitAccount.Select(lineItem => new RemitaSplit { /.../ });
```

How you simplify with LINQ in this case will depend on where/how you're populating `splitAccount`.  I'm assuming the example in the question is just a contrived line of code to show the type of that variable, because if that's the exact code then of course that loop will never iterate over an empty list.

The point is, if `splitAccount` is an expression tree which will ultimately materialize data from a backing data source, you may not be able to directly call `new RemitaSplit()` within a `.Select()` until you materialize all of the records into memory, such as with a `.ToList()`, and there may be performance considerations to be made on that.

Comment: @Brainiac005 This is what you should go for, if I understand the problem correctly.