# Is WCF result as JSON + unparseable curft needed for better security? How is it implemented?

Tags: wcf, json, xss, security, csrf

I'm reading about this [ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146798/why-do-people-put-code-like-throw-1-dont-be-evil-and-for-in-front-of) that describes ways to prevent Javascript based exploits.

1. Does it make sense to apply this technique to WCF-based services that return JSON?
2. How would this be implemented server side?
3. How would the client consume it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one way WebScriptEnablingBehavior -- the behavior of choice if you want a WCF service that works with ASP .NET AJAX -- deals with this. By default, its response mode is "WrappedResponse". If you watch this in action using Fiddler, it means that *every* response from the service -- even a simple number -- will wrapped in {d:} wrapper as follows:

```
 { "d" : return-value }
```

On the other hand, WebHttpBehavior is XML out-of-the-box, but if you switch it to JSON, you can choose between WrappedResponse and BareResponse. WrappedResponse is similar to WebScriptEnablingBehavior (if I remember correctly), but BareResponse would be unsecure JSON transmitted back as a direct return value.

Comment: Great find -  Thanks! I've been looking for this for a while.  Do you know the preferred way to consume this data?  Is it with a MSFT library or function... json... etc.

Comment: The preferred way to consume JSON produced with WebScriptEnablingBehavior is an ASP .NET AJAX webpage. The preferred way to consume WebHttpBehavior is your favorite scripting language.