# Strange JSON response in Google Plus

Tags: javascript, json, google-plus

While I was debugging an error in Google Plus (while importing FB contacts from Yahoo) I've discovered strange JSON response:

```
)]}'

[[["er",,,,,500]
,["e",2,,,57]
],'45932b7d6d6dc08e']
```

Is it some variation of JSONP? Reminds me of an SQL injection rather... So, what's the purpose of the closing brackets and quote at the beginning?

Comment: Smells like an XSS countermeasure

Comment: smells like someone wanted to let the world know he's on google+ ... or maybe thats teen spirit... I cant really tell

Comment: Whoa that is weird.  It's even served with content type "application/json" and yet is completely invalid json.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog, it looks more like an XSRF countermeasure to me.  The script at the top makes sure that it will not parse correctly when loaded cross-site via `<script src=...>` but when loaded via XMLHttp which obeys the same-origin policy, the breaker can be removed.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive I've received the answers quickly thanks to the interesting context. Also everyone may check the JSON responses by him/herself. But still, thanks for that valuable insight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's basically JSON with nulls removed and the garbage added at the beginning to thwart XSRF. Here's some PHP code that will decode it (from an unofficial Google Plus API I'm working on).

https://github.com/jmstriegel/php.googleplusapi/blob/master/lib/GooglePlus/GoogleUtil.php

Comment: Jason: I didn't get what "null" removed means. Care to elaborate?

Comment: genesis: rather than key-value pairs, the json returned by g+ contains a number of nested arrays. many of the fields in those arrays contain no value, but instead of being expressed as 'null', they are left empty. so, you'll see arrays that look like [,,,0] instead of [null,null,null,0]. javascript parsers seem to do okay with this, but it doesn't pass in php's json_decode function.  i assume the folks at google chose to do this to reduce transfer size.

Comment: also, to explain the code further: you simply throw away the first 5 characters, then sift through the remaining string looking for empty fields, inserting 'null' wherever you find one. after that, it should parse fine.

Comment: yes it works already. Wow. I didn't think about it! IT's so easy. Can you answer to this question, too ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672322/anti-xss-protection-by-adding-before-ajax-response

Answer (score 5):

It might be an XSRF defense similar to the one described at [What does a Ajax call response like 'for (;;); { json data }' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339790/what-does-ajax-call-response-like-for-json-data-mean)