# Securing JSON response through ajax in javascript (for(;;);)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, for-loop, response

I've been reading and I know there are similar questions, but I found no answer of what I'm looking for.

So it's about, for(;;); while(1); before the json string is outputted by an Ajax response.

Now what I wonder is how will this work? I'd like to try to use the same technique as many famous sites does like Facebook with for(;;);

So in the ajax.php file this is what I think has to be done:

ajax.php

```
$arr = array("value" => "something", "moreValues" => "moreSomething");
die("for(;;);".json_encode($arr));
```

Now the respone would be:

```
for(;;);{"value":"something","moreValues":"moreSomething"}
```

What shall I do with this string now? shall i remove for(;;); with a substr or something and then use JSON.parse(string); (Then why did I even send the for(;;); in the response if i'm going to remove it directly..?

And how will this help me with security issues, and how will a "user" enter the infinity loop for(;;); if something is wrong?

I know I am missing something, and I haven't found any example which demonstrates how to perform this. Anyone? And please if you find this question as a duplicate, please refer to an example where it's demonstrated in CODE not in words. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses **and** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339790/what-does-a-ajax-call-response-like-for-json-data-mean

Comment: i've read those articles 20 times, i'd like a better demonstrations in more code less words

Comment: If you've read those questions and answer 20 times, you wouldn't be asking questions like `What shall I do with this string now?`, `Then why did I even send the for(;;); in the response if i'm going to remove it directly..?`, `And how will this help me with security issues, and how will a "user" enter the infinity loop for(;;); if something is wrong?`

Comment: if you know the answer, could you show me in code how this works ?

Comment: You've already solved it - `shall i remove for(;;); with a substr or something and then use JSON.parse(string);`. The reasoning for everything is in the questions/answer I linked, the code is up to you, how you want to implement it. The response is just a string, so that seems fine to me

Comment: What you're missing is that when one refers to a URL via a `<script>` tag, you don't have the ability to modify the contents of the returned data, it's executed as given. But if you retrieve the data via AJAX, you can remove the prefix. The security comes from AJAX's cross-origin checking for AJAX.

Comment: alright starts to make some sense but I'm still stuck, could you show me an example?

Comment: It would just repeat the examples from the questions Ian linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with some simple Javascript, that might be used like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: mylink',
    type: 'post',
    complete: function(){
        self.removeAttr('disabled');    
        removeLoading();
    },
    success: function(data){
        s1 = new handleData(data);
        if(s1.getError()){
            return setMsgPopup(s1.getError(),1);
        }

        arr = s1.getResult();

    }
});
```

Here is the handleData class:

```
var handleData = (function(){
    var result=false;
    var error=false;
    var objSize=0;

    var handleData = function(data){
        fixedData = data;
        arr = data.split('for (;;);'); 

        if(!arr[1]){
            this.result = false;
        }else{
            fixedData = arr[1];
        }

        try{
            this.result = JSON.parse(fixedData);
        }catch(e){
            this.result = false;
        }

        if(this.result){
            if(this.result['t'] == undefined){
                if(this.result['error'] != undefined)
                    this.setError(this.result['msg']);
                else
                    this.setError("An error have occured.");
            }
            if(this.result['error'] != undefined)
                this.setError(this.result['msg']);

            if(this.result['t'])
                delete this.result['t'];            
        }else
            this.setError("An error have occured.");

        this.setSize();
    };

    handleData.prototype.setError = function(msgError){
        this.error = msgError;
    };

    handleData.prototype.getError = function(){
        return this.error;
    };

    handleData.prototype.getResult = function(){
        return this.result;
    };

    handleData.prototype.setSize = function(){
        if(!this.result)
            return;

        var size =0;
        for(key in this.result) {
            if(this.result.hasOwnProperty(key))
                size++;
        }
        this.objSize = size;
    }

    handleData.prototype.getSize = function(){
        return this.objSize;
    };

    return handleData;
})();
```

Notice this code is old as the question itself. It could be done better, but this is how I fixed it that time.