# A endpoint of facebooks internal API response body contains a for loop and followed by JSON blob, why?

Tags: json, api, rest, http

I debugged some of Facebook's internal endpoints and I found a wired response payload.It contains a for loop and JSON blob, why and what could you do with this loop?

Endpoint:

https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bootloader-endpoint/?modules=PagesCometHeaderActionsMenuWrapper.react&__user=100015575597279&__a=1&__dyn=7AzHK4HwBgC265Q2m3m8GEnxenFw9uu2i5U4e2O14xtoK3q322aewXwnEboG4E6icwJwpUe8hw8u1_w5nCxS320LE36xOfwwwto88hwKx-8wgolzUOm0Z84a3aUS2G2CaCzU7W8wnolwBgK7qwpE31wLxG4UaoC9xy48aU8od8-Uqxy1qxi4UaEW1-xS6FobrwKxm5oe8aU&__csr=i-ABExfiGWDGZmGJ5ybF2krpA9OeahlWQhhebaFUwFqZ34Xy9nNydnV11KyVaiE8CBx7b5PPi4nqiu-QFBbmjO5BllBeLIgWDiGyGWx2-ZrG8VF39KuG8jyLb8hqyuHo-nluKAuG-iiboGuad_BAmiOCoB5ja4ohyHF3SEqzoRqHBxm8wNCxqagF3Q2KPVpcGWB8Qcc8Fabj9O3R8Z2ol1jBh5XBxhy8hhGh9A9gl8i4W8FGvzUybyXgnoBaEJyJUqz6VWHYyjC8qidAAQozTF27KjCxCb89aFEw89rJeFQEvG46kx8hpEz9HgEEACA9xumgN8C9l4xfxG48jx6q4XwOwXp8lCyUcoAwlo6S585O5F42e-ESuh28eovy826zU1io17ywA40lXDwNwgbhF8a1GAyp8R90Vwlokwj86a5UO1nymUd81Zo6y0aFw9hwAwiUkFotO3o2iZw0zNg0BJDxS05M8&__req=4b&__beoa=1&__pc=EXP2%3Acomet_pkg&dpr=1&__ccg=EXCELLENT&__rev=1002161314&__s=1230in%3Abrvifg%3Amzu1bs&__hsi=6830485538918903931-0&__comet_req=1&fb_dtsg_ag=AQwgOCcgcTnzy1lHrbQZrrvOi7cJxlEv9ZUjz_UIpjST3Q%3AAQzhkyxOruEzbCZ3LoN8vL-SCR6BlPZlbK4ENaGWHzZyhw&jazoest=28405&__spin_r=1002161314&__spin_b=trunk&__spin_t=1590346344

Example json:

```
for (;;);{"bootloadable":{"BanzaiODS":{"r":["csr:_4b_2"],"rds":{"m":["BanzaiODS","BanzaiScuba"]}},"FbtLogging":{"r":["csr:_4b_3"]},"Banzai":{"r":["csr:_4b_4"],"rds":{"m":["BanzaiODS","BanzaiScuba"]}},"BanzaiScuba":{"r":["csr:_4b_5"],"rds":{"m":["BanzaiODS","BanzaiScuba"]}...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a protection againt JSON hijacking. The goal is to invalidate JSON data in order to prevent these kind of attacks.

You can find more information on JSON hijacking in the following links :

- a presentation of JSON hijacking : https://dev.to/antogarand/why-facebooks-api-starts-with-a-for-loop-1eob
- [Is facebook suddenly safe against JSON hijacking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206306/is-facebook-suddenly-safe-against-json-hijacking)
- [Is JSON Hijacking still an issue in modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers)