# How do I get jquery.Ajax to work with "throw 1; <dont be evil>" in front of json responses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, security, telerik

Google returns [Unparsable Cuft to the json response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3146798/328397)  like this:

```
throw 1; <dont be evil> { foo: bar}
```

- My current web applications use jQuery.Ajax to retrieve JSON data.  How should they be modified to consume valid data?

Here is a [relevant demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/ajaxbinding)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably remove the beginning part from the response:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    dataType: "jsonp text",
    success: function(data) {
        var jsonString = data.replace(/^throw 1; <dont be evil> /, "");
        var responseObject = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

        // do something with responseObject
        ...
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

To make the re-writing available in every Ajax call you could also register a global Ajax Converter in jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "text cleanedjson": function(data) {
            var jsonString = data.replace(/^throw 1; <dont be evil> /, "");
            return $.parseJSON(jsonString);
        }
    }
});

$.ajax(url, {
    dataType: "jsonp cleanedjson",
    success: function(responseObject) {
        // do something with responseObject
        ...
    }
});
```

You will still need to specify your defined `dataType` in the request options.

UPDATE 2:
If you need to tweak your existing calls to do the response cleanup automatically, you could  patch jQuery's `ajax` implementation to automatically use your converter in certain situations:

```
// store reference to original implementation
$._ajax_original = $.ajax;

// redefine jQuery's ajax function
$.ajax = function(url, settings) {
    if (… your test for applicability here (e.g. an url check) …) {
        settings.dataType = "jsonp cleanedjson";
    }
    return $._ajax_original(url, settings);
};
```

​
Note that this redefinition has to included after loading jQuery and before the first Ajax call is made. You may also need to consider that `$.ajax` can also [be called without a separate `url` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)...

Comment: `data.substring("throw1; <dont be evil> ".length)` is actually way faster, at least on V8.

Comment: Definitely an alternative, but "way faster", for a single replacement? Most likely absolutely irrelevant...

Comment: I'm using Telerik controls and editing the `$.ajax` command means I have to edit the source code and recompile.  I was thinking I could leave things as-is, and use prototype to redefine the "global ajax command" and allow all my compiled JSON to go unmodified.  Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  This is my first time redefining anything on jQuery.  Rather than define my own converter, can I redefine the "base/root" definition for JSON AJAX responses.  My goal is to avoid editing the source code and recompiling.  I believe this is required with the DataType setting you mention.

Comment: I have added a part about patching jQuery's `ajax` function. I would definitely not recommend tweaking the underlying XHR objects: handling the different implementations for all browsers would be quite some work...

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this a little simpler taking advantage of the `$.ajaxSetup` method:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

and using converters:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "text json": function (stringData) {
            return jQuery.parseJSON(stringData.replace("for(;;);", ""));
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is tap into every ajax call and makes the necessary conversion/replacement on the fly. It essentially takes your object which it reads as "text", replaces the unparseable cruft, and spits out a new json object.

Works great. I set it and forget it and it won't interfere with any non-tainted json.