# Requesting invalid JSON file using JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm requesting JSON file which has an invalid structure:

```
{}&&{
    "result": {
        "data": "01",
        "id": "02"
    }
}
```

I can't change JSON. It's on external server.
Firebug returns syntax error pointing to the && characters.

What should I do to get this invalid JSON?

My script:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
$.ajax({
url:"http://different-domain.com",
dataType: 'JSONP',
success: parseJSON
function parseJSON(data){
// do stuff with json
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you getting invalid JSON in the first place? Is there nothing you can do to change that?

Comment: If you cannot help returning valid `json`, why try to enforce the `jsonp` data type? Simply don't mention any data type in the ajax request. That would fetch the data but of course, you would not be able to consume it as a `json` object.

Comment: @NikhilPatil -- JSONP is required in order to issue a cross-domain request.

Comment: @ I can't change JSON. It is on external server

Comment: @maxedison - Ahh..I missed to read the URL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete` not a `success`. Than you could get RAW response before error comes. Then you can substr invalid chars while not to got parsed JSON:

```
$.ajax({
url:"http://different-domain.com",
dataType: 'JSONP',
complete: function(xhr){

    var raw= xhr.responseText
      , json
      , err
      ;

    while(raw.length && err)
    {
      // rewind state
      err= false;
      try {
        //parse JSON
        json= parseJSON(raw);
      }
      catch (e)
      {
        // Mark loop as invalid
        err= true;
      }

      // Get out if json is valid and parsed
      if (!err) break;

      // If loop is not broken try another one time: cut one char from invalid json and go on.
      raw= raw.substr(1);
    }

    if (!err)
    {
      console.log('YAPPPEEEEE :)');
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('NOPE :(');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but firebug says "raw is undefined"??

Comment: And xhr.responseText? What does console.log(xhr.responseText) return?

Comment: console.log(xhr.responseText) return "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

The `{}&&` prefix is chaff designed precisely to *stop* anyone outside different-domain.com from accessing the data. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146798/why-do-people-put-code-like-throw-1-dont-be-evil-and-for-in-front-of) for the background.

If you want a external interface so you can interact from outside the Same Origin Policy, you will have to get different-domain.com to change their script so that it supports the JSONP callback interface.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to remove the `&&` and anything that comes before it. Assuming that this is always the case, do the following in the `success` handler of the `$.ajax()` method:

```
succes: function(data){
    var goodJSON = data.slice(4);
    var myObject = $.parseJSON(goodJSON);
}
```

`myObject` will now hold the fully parsed JSON.

Comment: I have error not success so there is problem with JSONP request