# Add unparsable cruft to ASP.NET MVC JsonResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, security

In light of posts such as these:

[JSON unparseable cruft: Why so serious?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723226/json-unparseable-cruft-why-so-serious)

[Why do people put code like "throw 1; <dont be evil>" and "for(;;);" in front of json responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146798/why-do-people-put-code-like-throw-1-dont-be-evil-and-for-in-front-of)

[Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

I would like to follow the advice laid out in the following answer: [How should web app developers defend against JSON hijacking?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/7003/8340)

Is there an easy way to add an unparsable cruft to JSON responses built using `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`? The `security.se` post suggests that I use `</*` at the beginning of the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom action result to perform this:

```
public class SafeJsonResult: JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</*");
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

and then use it instead of the default one:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new SafeJsonResult
    {
        Data = new { Foo = "bar" },
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    };
}
```