# Why is google appending `/*""*/` to JSON responses?

Tags: ajax, security, rest

Google is appending `/*""*/` at the end of all JSON responses and I think it must be a security mechanism. Could you help me to get more information about the attack and its defense mechanisms?

Comment: Post a code snippet that helps us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Do you know the attack name so that i can get more info about it?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Just capture and view google JSON responses. try searching in http://www.google.com and view the response.

Comment: @hkazemi see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses), it's called JSON hijacking.

Comment: See [JSON unparseable cruft: Why so serious?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14723226/413180) and [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a defense mechanism against [JSON Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) attack.