# ajax converters and IE7

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing, converters

Using a [unparseable cruft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146798/why-do-people-put-code-like-throw-1-dont-be-evil-and-for-in-front-of) on my ajax responses.

Works great, except IE7 which throws a failure. Any thoughts on why the failure?

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "js/zipcodeLookup.json", //mock json response
         contentType: "application/json",  
        dataType:"text json",
        data: "{postalcode: '" + $(myField).val() + "', country: '" + myCountry + "'}",
        success: function(data) {
            //do something here

        },
        error: function(){
        alert('failure');
      }

     });
```

ajax converter:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({ 
            converters: { "text json": function (stringData) { 
                        return JSON.parse(stringData.replace('for(;;);', '')); 
            } } 
});
```

and json:

```
for(;;);{
    "isError": "false",
    "city": "Springfield",
    "juris": "IL"
}
```

***EDIT***

and the correct answer is that I stupidly overlooked my parse method - use `jQuery.parseJSON()` instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE < 8 doesn't have native support for `JSON`. Do you have any fallback mechanism for IE7?

For browsers without native JSON support you should use [this](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library

You could implement a fallback mechanism like this

```
<script>window.JSON|| 
    document.write("<script src='js/json2.js'>\x3C/script>")
</script>
```

Comment: stupid oversight on my part - I pulled the converter off of an example, and forgot to change it to `jQuery.parseJSON()`. Thanks for helping me realize that