# javascript "for (;;);" structure

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty “for” loop in Facebook ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058401/empty-for-loop-in-facebook-ajax)
>   [what does AJAX call response like for (;;); { json data } mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339790/what-does-ajax-call-response-like-for-json-data-mean)

While analyzing some facebook ajax requests body i noticed that every code starts with 
`for (;;);`, folloed by an json object

something like

```
for (;;); {"a":1,"b":"\u003cdiv"}
```

I googled after this structure but found nothing.

What could be the reason for this "for" structure at the beginning of every ajax response?

Comment: it's endless `for` loop according to javascript syntax

Comment: It could be for preventing XSS - the code after the for would never get executed...

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @AndyE - Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058401/empty-for-loop-in-facebook-ajax

Comment: @JamesAllardice: looks like there's a few.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` like this (note that there isn't the ';' after the bracket):

```
for (;;)
```

means an infinite loop where the statements executed are those between the brackets.

Instead, a for like this:

```
for (;;);
```

means an infinite loop with no statement.

Answer (score 0):

Its for security, it keeps out other clients that try to intercept their AJAX calls. 
Basicly if you'd eval it straight away your browser would crash because of the endless loop, they just add another layer of (ob)security.

Nothing to worry about for you.

Comment: That doesn't strike me as secure. Or even remotely hard to get around.

Comment: And now that I know about it, what prevents me from removing the first part of the response and evaluating the rest?

Comment: Its something, and it keeps some script-kiddies out.

Comment: @Felix, absolutely nothing, and thats what Facebook most likely does itself. However that argument could be used for every type of security, what prevents you from just NOP-ing out the security routines.

You have to start somewhere.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong about why it's added, but it won't keep anyone out. If you have the will to work out how to intercept it it won't have to crash more than a couple of times before you work out why..

Comment: That argument could certainly not be used for every type of security. Two way hashing/encryption comes to mind for example.