# Facebook strange javascript that contains endless loop

Tags: javascript, facebook

When I debugged my facebook apps, I found a strange facebook javascript that contain an endless loop, but it has no body. What is the purpose of this for(;;); loop?

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"content":[],"custom_stories":[],"newest":0}}
```

URL:https://apps.facebook.com/ajax/canvas_ticker.php?__a=1

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058401/empty-for-loop-in-facebook-ajax

Comment: It could be a way of preventing the text returned from being `eval`-ed. It would need to be parsed.

Comment: I had to read the answer on that question a few times before it made sense to me. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: @jwiscarson I don't get the point :-? It's hard for me to understand :-s

Comment: it's just an endless loop - like calling `while(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I linked to a duplicate, the answer on that question is difficult to understand. To the best of my understanding, it means:

Facebook does not want you to directly use the results from their AJAX directly. They want you to go through their API. They don't want you to include their scripts, make use of their internal AJAX responses, and then have direct access to the data returned from those responses.

Comment: but how a endless loop prevent me to make use of their internal AJAX?

Comment: An endless loop will never return data to you.