# Setters are no longer called when setting properties in object initializers: what does this mean?

Tags: javascript

On this [JS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) page it says this:

> **JavaScript 1.8.1 note**
>
> Starting in JavaScript 1.8.1, setters are no
> longer called when setting properties in object and array
> initializers.

I just can't figure out what this is trying to tell me.

Comment: `This article is in need of a technical review.` - refer to ES5.1 spec for modern getter/setter syntax (unless you need, for some reason, to tinker with old firefox's getters/setter. And in that case, i am sorry for you)

Comment: c69 - wah? where would I find that?

Comment: At the top of the page. There is a red warning.

Comment: c69 - o The ES spec doesn't help either, I am sooooo tired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this refers to the issue of JSON hijacking. Have a look at

- [Is it possible to do 'JSON hijacking' on modern browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8587567/1048572)
- http://incompleteness.me/blog/2007/03/05/json-is-not-as-safe-as-people-think-it-is/
- http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx, http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx
- http://hackademix.net/2009/01/13/you-dont-know-what-my-twitter-leaks/

To repost my answer from [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12734377/1048572):

> According to the specification, neither Array ([EcmaScript 5.1
>   §11.1.4](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.4)) nor Object literals
>   ([EcmaScript 5.1 §11.1.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5)) should be
>   hijackable:
>
> - They call "*the standard built-in constructor with that name*", not what you might have overwritten at `window.Array` or `window.Object`
> - They use [[defineOwnProperty]], which does absolutely not take care of any setters on `Object.prototype`.

Nowadays, this should not be an issue any more in ES 5.1-compliant browsers.

Answer (score 7):

This code-snippet:

```
var o = {};
o.seven = 7;
```

and this code-snippet:

```
var o = { seven: 7 };
```

are normally equivalent; but if they're preceded by this code-snippet:

```
Object.prototype.__defineSetter__('seven', function(x) { alert(x); });
```

then only the former will alert `7` (because the setter is called by `o.seven = 7`, but not by `o = { seven: 7 }`), and only the latter will actually set `o.seven` to `7`.