# React - Array are passed as their length

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm new to react and i'm trying to use hooks for my project.
I need to pass an array from parent to child, just that when I put the array in the props it just pass its length.

```
ParentComponent.js
export default function NewHome() {

const [isReady, setReadyState] = useState(false);

const [regionWithValue, setRegionWithValue] = useState([]);


function getRegion() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/region")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                result.forEach((el) => {
                    setRegionWithValue(regionWithValue.push(el));
                })
                setReadyState(true);
            },
            (error) => {
                setErrore(true);
            }
        );
};
useEffect(() => {
    getRegion();
    console.log(regionWithValue);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
},[]);
if (ReadyState) {
console.log(regionWithValue);
return(
<ChildComponent region={regionWithValue}/>
)
}
```

The console.log in useEffect() actually print the correct array with data fetched, but the second console.log right before the return, just print out the array size, so I can't pass it to the ChildComponent. I don't know if is cause lifecycle so I'm getting all wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason your then isn't just doing .then((results) => setRegionWithValue(results))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
setRegionWithValue(regionWithValue.push(el));
```

`push` returns the length and not the array you pushed to

You can do it like this:

```
setRegionWithValue(v => ([...v, el]));
```

See: [Why does Array.prototype.push return the new length instead of something more useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34259126/104380)

Stating from [`Array.prototype.push()` MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

> *The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.*

Comment: Why not simplify it even more to simply .then((results) => setRegionWithValue(results))?

Comment: @TallPaul - i didn't bother reading this huge chunk of code, I just immediately saw the problem and corrected him regarding this

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) This actually solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

You cant use push on a React Hook. You need to get the previous state and add to that state (prevState is the industry standard naming convention) . This can be accomplished in your fetch like this:

```
    setRegionWithValue(prevState => (
          setRegionWithValue([...prevState, result])
        ));
```

**This will always add to the state, if you want to just create a new state everytime you fetch then you should just use:**

`setRegionWithValue(result)`

Comment: this is incorrect. the `push` method has nothing to do with the *React Hook*. This problem is javascript-related and not React-related

Comment: its the exact same answer as below... LOL ... it is correct, and as i said the push method should not be used on react hooks.

Comment: Also since hooks are only on React, it is 100% react related and not javascript related