# Why the map function doesn't work in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I want to build an application that looks like this:

[image]

Basically the user can put his name and comment and post it. The posted comments will be displayed in the bottom. I'm using Tailwind CSS to style the app. Below is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


class MyName extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div className="rounded border border-indigo-400 m-8 p-2">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-stretch space-y-2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Who you are?" className="border border-gray-500" value={this.state.currentUser} onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({currentUser: e.target.value});
                }} />
                <textarea placeholder="Say something" className="h-32 border border-gray-500" value={this.state.currentData} onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({currentData: e.target.value});
                }}></textarea>
                <button className="bg-green-400 text-green-100 rounded py-1 hover:bg-green-600" onClick={() => {
                    if (this.state.currentUser && this.state.currentData) {
                        this.setState({
                            comments: this.state.comments.push({
                                user: this.state.currentUser,
                                data: this.state.currentData
                            })
                        });
                        this.state.currentUser = "";
                        this.state.currentData = "";
                    }
                }}>Post comment
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-8">
                {this.comments_section()}
            </div>
        </div>);
    }

    comments_section() {
        if (this.state.comments.length == 0) {
            return <span>No Comments.</span>
        }
        else {
            console.log(Array.isArray(this.state.comments));
            console.log(this.state.comments);
            return (<ul className="space-y-4">{this.state.comments.map((item) =>
                <li className="flex items-start space-x-2" key={item.user + item.data}>
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-start space-y-1">
                        <img className="rounded-full" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />
                        <span className="text-xs text-gray-500">{item.user}</span>
                    </div>
                    <span>{item.data}</span>
                </li>)}
            </ul>)
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            currentUser: "",
            currentData: "",
            comments: [{
                user: "User One",
                data: "Hi, hello world!"
            }, {
                user: "User Two",
                data: "Hi, hello world!"
            }]
        }
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyName />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

The problem is that when I type something in the inputs and click the button, it errors out and states *this.state.comments.map* is not a function. I added some *console.log* statement to debug it and found that at first *this.state.comments* is an array. But once I clicked the button, it is not. How to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: `this.state.comments.push` returns the number of elements in the array. Please add seperate functions instead of adding these logic in jsx. Also, `this.state.currentUser = ""` should also be updated via `setState` and not directly mutated via assignement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Array.prototype.push return the new length instead of something more useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259126/why-does-array-prototype-push-return-the-new-length-instead-of-something-more-us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState({
   comments: this.state.comments.push({
     user: this.state.currentUser,
     data: this.state.currentData
   })
});
```

array.push returns a number, which is the length of the array. So you're setting state.comments to a number, and numbers don't have a map method.

You shouldn't use push for this, since it mutates the array, and react requires your state to be immutable. Additionally, you have a couple lines where you're manually setting this.state.currentUser and this.state.currentData. Changes to the state should always be through set state, not manual modification of this.state.

```
const newComments = [...this.state.comments, {
  user: this.state.currentUser,
  data: this.state.currentData
}]
this.setState({ 
  comments: newComments,
  currentUser: "",
  currentData: ""
});
```

An additional improvement: since you're basing your new state on your old state, you should use the function version of setState. React will pass you the most recent version of the state, which eliminates the possibility that you're using a stale version of the state (your code probably can't run into this bug, but it can happen in more complicated cases, so it's good to get in the habit)

```
this.setState(prev => {
  const newComments = [...prev.comments, {
    user: prev.currentUser,
    data: prev.currentData
  }]
  return { 
    comments: newComments
    currentUser: "",
    currentData: ""
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.push` returns a number i.e. length of the array so you are basically setting comments to its length.

```
if (this.state.currentUser && this.state.currentData) {
  let { comments, currentUser, currentData } = this.state;
    comments.push({
     user: currentUser,
     data: currentData
    })
 this.setState({comments, currentUser : "", currentData: "" })
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be useful.

Comment: @PrathameshMore I have added a small explanation regarding the cause of issue. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a react expert but I think you need to return your jsx from the map like this:

```
<ul className="space-y-4">
{this.state.comments.map((item) => return (
                <li className="flex items-start space-x-2" key={item.user + item.data}>
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-start space-y-1">
                        <img className="rounded-full" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />
                        <span className="text-xs text-gray-500">{item.user}</span>
                    </div>
                    <span>{item.data}</span>
                </li>))}
            </ul>
```

Comment: if there is no `{}` in arrow function, return is implicit