# after using React Natives usestate function, includes method fails

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-state, asyncstorage

I'm trying to include a favorites mechanism to my react native codes, but I'm facing a problem:

When the page renders first, `favs.includes` function works as expected. But when I clicked the favorite button, it raises an error

`TypeError: favs.includes is not a function. (In 'favs.includes(id)', 'favs.includes' is undefined)`

```
const getFavs = async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.getItem("favs").then((res) => {
    if (res !== [] && res !== null && res !== "") {
      return setFavs(JSON.parse(res));
    } else {
      return setFavs([]);
    }
  });
};
useEffect(() => {
  getFavs();
  console.log(favs.includes(id));
  return console.log(typeof favs);
}, []);

return (
  <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
    {favs.includes(id) ? (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          AsyncStorage.removeItem("favs", id);
        }}
      >
        <Icon name="star" size={25} color="orange" solid />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ) : (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: "red" }}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(typeof favs);
          setFavs(favs.push(id));
          console.log(typeof favs);
          AsyncStorage.setItem("favs", JSON.stringify(favs));
          setFav(true);
        }}
      >
        <Icon name="star" size={25} color="orange" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line in your click handler

```
setFavs(favs.push(id))
```

which sets `favs` to a number not an array. [`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array after push, not the array itself. see [Why does Array.prototype.push return the new length instead of something more useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259126/why-does-array-prototype-push-return-the-new-length-instead-of-something-more-us).

Also, using `push()` on a state array mutates the array, you should instead

```
setFavs(prevFavs => [...prevFavs, id])
// or
setFavs(prevFavs => prevFavs.concat(id))
```

Your last error is assuming that calling `console.log` after your `setState` call will reflect the change in state when it will in fact log the old(current) state value. The updated state value won't be available until the next render cycle. see [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is usually because of when the component rendered at first, `favs` state is still empty or `getFavs` async function wasn't finished.

Maybe you can try to give condition to where `favs.includes` invoked such as:

```
           {favs && favs.includes && favs.includes(id)? // make sure favs is truthy and favs.includes property existed
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
                AsyncStorage.removeItem('favs',id);
            }}>
            <Icon name = "star" size={25} color="orange" solid />
            </TouchableOpacity >
            :
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={{height:100,width:100,backgroundColor:'red'}} onPress={()=>{
                console.log(typeof(favs))
                setFavs(favs.push(id))
                console.log(typeof(favs))
                AsyncStorage.setItem('favs',JSON.stringify(favs))
                setFav(true)
            }}>
            <Icon name = "star" size={25} color="orange" />
            </TouchableOpacity >
            }
```

Please let me know if this solve your issue or not, thanks

Comment: Thanks for comment, it was not the reason. Pilchard's way did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I see two problems with your code.

Firstly, I do not see your `useState` usage. It should be

```js
const [favs, setFavs] = useState([]);
```

Secondly, you are mixing asynchronous and synchronous code. You are calling `getFavs`, which contains a call to asynchronous storage which is executed "outside" of main program thread. And immediately after that you are calling `favs.includes()`, which of course will not work, because the async call did not come through yet.