# Override reserved words (set false = true)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override the reserved words? I would never do this, but it has caught my attention and made me curious.

Can I make `false = true` in Javascript? I've seen some pranks on various sites, where people override the default reserved words with the opposite (not Javascript).

Is this possible in Javascript though?

Comment: where did you see this `false=true` atleast for me it gives an error.

Comment: @Mritunjay The user means actually making `false` the keyword as the value `true`.

Comment: false is value, and can't be converted to true, this is similar if you ask can you set 5 to 2 ( 5 = 2)

Comment: What I mean is protected words. Not variables. My bad. I want to know if it's possible to set `false = true`, because I have seen something similar as a prank in another language.

Comment: It _used_ to be possible to set `undefined` to some other value, but fortunately that's no longer the case.

Comment: @Alnitak `undefined` is not a reserved word

Comment: @Grissom on Chrome at least the parser complains if you do `var false = true` because it detects the _keyword_ where a variable identifier would be expected.  Only if you just do `false = true` will it complain about finding an rvalue on the LHS.

Comment: @zerkms I never said it was, but it's the closest scenario to what the OP described that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Alnitak "A JavaScript Boolean represents one of two values: true or false." http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp

Comment: If you're gonna keep quoting w3fools at me I'm leaving...

Comment: Wait, you want to say that false is not value?

Comment: @Grissom those are "boolean literals", if you want to give it some precise name as per the standard.

Comment: I found another oddity with `undefined` - if you do `a = (undefined = 5)` then the result of the RHS assignment operator in the parentheses is still 5 and that's what's assigned to `a`, even though `undefined` is not modified.

Comment: @Alnitak that's because the assignment operator returns the `rval` and in non-strict mode the operation is successful (even though it does not modify the `undefined`)

Comment: @Alnitak, you can call it as you want, but you can't still prove that is possible to assign true to false.

Comment: @zerkms interesting - I had always assumed that the assignment operator would return the (new) value of the `lval`

Comment: @Alnitak http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation --- see 1h

Comment: @Grissom what is your point in this dialogue?

Comment: @zerkms yup, just been reading that.  I tested it too, by creating an object with a getter and setter on a property and doing `var a = obj.prop = 10` and showing that the getter isn't called (http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/qbeff8e3/)

Comment: @zerkms, I mean it no makes sense to post examples and links which are not answer on question.

Comment: @Grissom these are comments, not answers. Comments can be virtually about anything. Like: it was a nice day here today.

Comment: I rest my case, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in JS. `false` and `true` are literals that will resolve to exactly those values - the same is true for numbers, strings and `null`.

Moreover, they are reserved words, so you cannot use them as variables names - in contrast to `undefined`, which you [could shadow and (prior to ES5) even overwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680375/1048572). Also, [ES5 refined the workings of array and object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13040748/1048572) so that you cannot any more mess with those either.

Answer (score 0):

Nop, it is not possible to use reserved words as variable in JS : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: "protected words" o_O

Comment: Yes, reserved words is what I meant. No results on Google for "protected words" or "protected variables".. Now I find loads. Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes "reserved words" is better `:)`

Comment: "Reserved Words" is also [what the specification actually calls them](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1).

Comment: @JamesThorpe I know it's not... good to override them. I would never, but it would be interesting to know.