# Hijacking .__proto__

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, proto

When an object is instantiated, be it a string/function/etc, a `__proto__` property is included.  This property seems to be generated by the `__proto__` accessors in `Object.prototype`...

```
Object.prototype == {
    __defineGetter__    : __defineGetter__()
    __defineSetter__    : __defineSetter__()
    __lookupGetter__    : __lookupGetter__()
    __lookupSetter__    : __lookupSetter__()
    constructor         : Object()
    hasOwnProperty      : hasOwnProperty()
    isPrototypeOf       : isPrototypeOf()
    propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable()
    toLocaleString      : toLocaleString()
    toString            : toString()
    valueOf             : valueOf()
    get __proto__       : __proto__()               //  getter
    set __proto__       : __proto__()               //  setter
};
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to hijack this `__proto__` property to execute a code block when an object is instantiated.  The idea being to replace the `__proto__` property with a custom property that executes some code before calling the original accessors to create the `__proto__` on the new instance.

If that makes sense!  If not here's where I'm up to:

```
pro = Object.prototype;
tmp = {};
Object.defineProperty(tmp, '__proto__',
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(pro, '__proto__')
);
delete pro.__proto__;
Object.defineProperty(pro, '__proto__',{
    get:function(){
        console.warn('intercepted Get __proto__');
        return tmp.__proto__;
    },
    set(p){
        console.warn('intercepted Set __proto__');
        tmp.__proto__ = p;
    }
});
```

Can't tell if it works properly yet but it's only an example to try and show you what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: "*a `__proto__` property is included*" - well, no, it's **inherited**. You wouldn't say that a `hasOwnProperty` property is included in every object, would you?

Comment: No, you cannot hijack them *any more*, [and that's a good thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13040748/1048572).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it is possible to hijack this `__proto__` property to execute a code block when an object is instantiated.

No. The `__proto__` property's accessors aren't called when the object is created. They're only called when you get or set `__proto__`. You can see what happens when an object is created by looking at [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-objectcreate):

> **ObjectCreate (*proto* [ , *internalSlotsList* ])**
>
> The abstract operation ObjectCreate with argument *proto* (an object or null) is used to specify the runtime creation of new ordinary objects. The optional argument *internalSlotsList* is a List of the names of additional internal slots that must be defined as part of the object. If the list is not provided, a new empty List is used. This abstract operation performs the following steps:
>
> 1. If *internalSlotsList* was not provided, let *internalSlotsList* be a new empty List.
> 2. Let *obj* be a newly created object with an internal slot for each name in *internalSlotsList*.
> 3. Set *obj*'s essential internal methods to the default ordinary object definitions specified in 9.1.
> 4. Set the [[Prototype]] internal slot of *obj* to *proto*.
> 5. Set the [[Extensible]] internal slot of *obj* to **true**.
> 6. Return *obj*.

Recall that `__proto__` *isn't* the object's prototype reference; that's the `[[Prototype]]` slot in the object, which isn't accessible in code. `__proto__` is just a (web-only) means of accessing the value in that slot. (The general way, which also works outside browsers whereas `__proto__` officially doesn't, is `getPrototypeOf` / `setPrototypeOf` on `Object` and `Reflect`.) Also note that not all objects have `__proto__` because not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`:

```js
var o1 = {};
console.log("__proto__" in o1); // true
var o2 = Object.create(null);   // No prototype
console.log("__proto__" in o2); // false
var o3 = Object.create(o2);     // Has a prototype, but still no link to Object.prototype
console.log("__proto__" in o3); // false
```

Comment: I'm assuming the compiler calls `get __proto__` when instantiating an object?

Comment: @LostInCyberSpace: No, the engine doesn't call any accessors when instantiating the object.