# Handlebar.js without Ajax?

Tags: ajax, handlebars.js

I want to use handlebar.js template for my own website to display list of articles.
But if I would like to use handlebar.js, I don't have the choice to call my data by ajax request trought an API i think.
Then in console or JS file, users could see where my data are stored and catch the json output.
Is there any way to protect this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to show data to the user without letting the user see the data.

You should change your API service to not return anything you don't want the user to see.

Comment: i'm building news website. Is it good then to use the same api for both mobile application and handlebar.js template for web site desktop version ? My api will be free to see to everyone because of handlebar ajax..i don't want to, got it ?

Comment: @Klaitos: Sharing the API is a good idea. If you don't want people to see things for free then you need to build authentication and access control into the API (mobile or not), your server should never trust client connections more than it absolutely has to.

Comment: @Klaitos: If you have an API, people will discover and use it.  It doesn't matter whether you use it for the desktop version or not.  If you want to restrict access, you need actual access control (authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Well, use sessions and normal protection against direct web request. Don't forgot that ajax is only a call made to a public URL.

Moreover, you can also checkout this related question about how you can secure JSON: [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Comment: I'm not afraid about crosssite forgery but from user who wanna steal my datas to put them on their own website.

Comment: Then you can't do anything. Data will be there as it is displayed to user. The only "more" secure way could be to offuscate the data by encoding it and decoding or just by minifying it - but that won't prevent anything, just discourage. After that, your only real protection is copyright and lawyer.