# defer script execution for some time

Tags: javascript, deferred-execution

Is it possible, in javascript, to defer the execution of a self-execution function that resides at the top level closure? (For you to understand, jQuery uses this. It has a self-execution function at global scope)

My objective here is to make the whole external script to execute at a later time without deferring it's download, such that it downloads as soon as possible and executes after an event (I decide when that event happens).

I found this also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onbeforescriptexecute

Sounds like a "part 1" of what I want. If I cancel, the script is not executed. but then... How do I effectively execute it later?

**Note1:** I have absolutely no control over that external script, so I cannot change it.

**Note2:** Both me and who requested this does not care if there's slowness in IE due to stuff like this (yeah, true! (s)he's anti-IE like me)

Edit (additional information):
@SLaks The server sends the default headers that apache send (so-it-seems) plus a cache-control header ordering to cache for 12 hours.
From the POV of the rules about domains, it is cross-domain.
I'm not allowed to change the definitions about the other server. I can try to asking for it, though.

Comment: What caching headers does the script send? Is it on your domain? Can you enable cross-domain XHR?

Comment: What about if you load the js in a img tag for the browser to cache it, then add it to a script tag for the execution at the time you choose?

Comment: @MennanKara That sounds like an interesting approach. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do with the `<script>` tag because you can't get the text of an external script included that way to wrap it in code to delay it. If you could, that would open up a whole new world of possibilities with Cross Site Request Forgery ([CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)).

However, you can fetch the script with an AJAX request as long as it's hosted at the same domain name. Then you can delay its execution.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/myscript.js',
    success: function(data) {
        // Replace this with whatever you're waiting for to delay it
        $.ready(function() {
            eval(data);
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
I've never used `$.getScript()` myself since I use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for including scripts, so I don't know if it will help with what you need, but have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

**FYI**
If you want to know what I'm talking about with the CSRF attacks, [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses).

Comment: I don't use jQuery, but I know what that code does and I can translate it to a native DOM.

Comment: @brunoais: I doubt you can translate `jQuery.getScript` to native functions easily :-)

Comment: @Bergi You don't have to use `getScript`, as I domonstrated. It's not really hard though. All you have to do is a normal XMLHttpRequest without the extra help of jQuery. It's still not that hard to do. If it would be more helpful I could translate this to vanilla JS for you.

@brunoais If this solves your problem don't forget to mark it :) Thanks!

Comment: @Justin: Thanks no, I know how it would look like with vanilla JS. Yet I know as well how `getScript` is implemented, and it could get complicated if you wanted to replicate all of its anti-quirks behaviour :-)

Comment: @Bergi getScript() does not solve, anyway. I'll use something similar to how RequireJS does, but much more simplified. I don't need this fully optimized for IE < 9 (I just needs to work somehow) and I'd rather not have more scripts loaded into the page. 5 is already more than enough...

Comment: @JustinWarkentin I'll give more time to this question. There might be better answers in the meantime....