# Windows Phone 8 Web Browser Download JSON

Tags: .net, json, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, windows-phone

I am trying to extract JSON by opening this [link](http://api.quora.com/api/logged_in_user?fields=inbox,notifs,following,followers) but the web browser control doesn't render it. As in, if you open the above link in desktop browser, it will show you the JSON output but on IE control on Windows Phone it doesn't and instead it says it cannot find an app to open it.

I dont want to use WebClient since the Quora Login cookies/credential is stored in the web browser so I cant use WebClient as user cannot login then.

Please help, I am unable to find a solution. I want to extract the JSON output and then show the user the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a public API you are accessing. Quora prepends "while(1);" to the beginning of the JSON response so that if you do try and hijack it, then your application will not be able to parse it.

See: [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Comment: I am able to open the link on Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE control.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** open the JSON for rendering in the Internet Explorer control on Windows Phone. You will have to download it and then take the appropriate actions.

Comment: Hmm, but in order to download it, Quora needs login cookies which is stored in the IE web browser control!