# Prepend JSON response from ExpressJS

Tags: json, express

A common security method to prevent JSON Injection is to prepend all JSON responses. Google uses `while(1)` or `&&&START&&&`, facebook uses `for(;;);`

Is it possible to prepend all JSON responses from ExpressJS?

Comment: How does that work? All examples aren't proper JSON.

Comment: Its a common approach to prevent JSON hijacking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses