# Why use CJSON encode when we have json_encode

Tags: php, json, yii

I am building an API for a website using Yii. I know that there is a utility class called CJson and has a function called encode.

As far as I know there are additional parameters that can be customized in the native json_encode function like the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK which is really useful. It creates

```
{
    "id": 17
}
```

instead of Yii's CJSON encode which makes the '17' a string.

```
{
    "id": "17"
}
```

So my question is whether there is any reason I should use CJSON encode instead of the built in PHP function json_encode ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only thing I can think minimum php version support.

Yii support php 5.1 as minimum version See [Yii Installation Page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation) . While json_encode/json_decode introduced in php 5.2. So It can be a reason for Yii having a library for CJson.

Answer (score 4):

This question is old. I am working with Yii 1.4, PHP 5.4.

The difference i found was 'json_encode' encodes only class properties, while as 'CJSON::encode' encodes only properties listed at the class documentation using @property annotation... This is true at least for CActiveRecord

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old topic, but wanted to add another reason.

By doing all JSON encoding through a helper class like CJSON you can override default behavior. For example [you can use it to add a token to prevent JSON hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @kuldeep.kamboj, I should say `CJSON::encode` will treat that `17` as an integer if you define the `data type` of the value like this:

```
// PHP
$toBeConverted = array('id' => (int) 17); // or (int) $myInteger

$jsonString = \CJSON::encode($toBeConverted);    

// $jsonString will be:
{
    "id": 17
}
```