# How to convert Ajax response object in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below data received from Ajax call as response

```
{d: "ADIDAS,NIKE,PUMA, METRONAUT }
```

Now, i need to convert this into array as shown below

```
["ADIDAS","NIKE","PUMA","METRONAUT"]
```

How can i do this using jquery/javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ajax response array object to javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271611/convert-ajax-response-array-object-to-javascript-array)

Comment: Did you try something?  Did you get stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 let k={d: "ADIDAS,NIKE,PUMA, METRONAUT" }
    
    let s=k.d.split(",");
    console.log(s)
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```js
var responseObject = { d: "ADIDAS,NIKE,PUMA, METRONAUT" };
var resultArray = responseObject.d.split(",");
    
console.log(resultArray);
```