# PHP Fetch data from database and encode into JSON format Yii framework

Tags: php, json, yii, encode

I'm kinda struggling with yii framework. I would like to connect to mobile app from my php server. How should I do the Json encoding and sent to mobile app in yii framework?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @imcrazy Let me know if my answer was help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Q: How should I do the Json encoding and sent to mobile app in yii framework?

#### A:

```
echo CJSON::encode($myArray);
```

## Q: If I want to pass in just user_name to mobile app, is it possible? How should I do that?

#### A:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='user_name';  // only select the 'user_name' column
$criteria->condition='user_id=:user_id';
$user_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'user_id');
if(FALSE===$user_id){
   header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 not found');
   return false;
}

$criteria->params=array(':user_id'=>$user_id); // check 
$user=Users::model()->find($criteria); // $params is not needed
```

//echo json as written at answer #1

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Yii way to do it is

```
echo CJSON::encode($myArray);
```

The underlying code use json_encode, but there are advantages discussed here :
[Why use CJSON encode when we have json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358159/why-use-cjson-encode-when-we-have-json-encode)

Answer (score 0):

Im using this:

```
 public function actionGetUser($user_id)
        {   
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            $user = User::model()->findAll();
            echo CJSON::encode($user);
            Yii::app()->end();
     }
```

this does work when i test: localhost/myproject/index.php/user/getuser/user_id

Is it possible for json to just encode just one attribute and send to mobile app? Example: there are the attributes like: user_id, user_name, user_email, user_photo

If I want to pass in just user_name to mobile app, is it possible? How should I do that?