# Rack middleware to to prepend while(1); to all ajax/json requests

Tags: javascript, ruby, rack, middleware

I'd like to do something similar to what Google/Facebook do in this post:
[Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Adding `while(1);` to the beginning of script and json posts, using Rack middleware in a rails app.  This way we can go back to doing ajax GET requests (which may or may not have an authentity_token or or sensitive data embedded in the response).

We also have an API which needs to not use this, so I am thinking some url matching where the middleware does not kick in.

Can anyone point me in the right direction what this code might look like?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a lot of questions molded into one, I think.

The middleware itself would look something(haven't checked it, but it feels right) like this:

```
class AntiHijackingMiddleware
 def call(env)
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env) # save initial state

    if env["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] == "XMLHttpRequest" && headers['Content-type'].to_s.include?("application/json")
        body = "while(1);"+body
        headers['Content-Length'] = Rack::Utils.bytesize(body.to_s).to_s
    end

    [status, headers, body]
 end
end
```

You can add additional conditions on `env["REQUEST_URI"]` to do url matching.

Adding it to Rails' middleware stack is boilerplate.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!  This would prepend it.  The client would have to strip it also right?  I saw this this example also http://blag.7tonlnu.pl/blog/2012/09/27/json-hijacking-in-rails/ but it's not clear to me how jquery would strip the while(1) for any ajax request (in addition to json).  But perhaps I'm missing something?  Thanks again!