# What is for(;;) in Facebook long poling request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, long-polling

Hi i have question which means **for (;;);** in Facebook long polling request ? This statement is in every file which is long polled from Facebook server.

Thank you

Comment: I know that is infinite loop but i still don't know why facebook have this statement in every Long pulled file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690 may be similar, just with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way this infinite loop is executed; just try it in your console. A simple operation like integer incrementing will freeze your screen:

```
    var a = 1;
    for (;;) {
        a++;
    }
```

It may be just a small trap for anyone who tries to `eval` their script, or something.

Comment: you're right, I believe I recall from when this came up before somewhere - this is intended as a security measure.

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinite loop.
The same as `while(true)`.

I guess they use it instead of `while` to make a file size smaller.

Answer (score 1):

in a for loop all params are optional, this is basically an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

that's an infinite loop,

```
for(;;) {[condition to break + loop logic]}
while ([condition to break]) { }
do { } while ([condition to break]);
```

for example, you can use it to repeat certain operation multiple times and it's up to you to decide when to stop iterating using a break statement. (just a fancy way of using a for instead of a do/while)

cheers!