# while(1) JSON injection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I read this post [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Can help what kind of php script for this  ?

I try

```
$time=time();
$hash=md5(mt_rand(1,200000));

$arr = array('time' => $time, 'hash' => $hash);
while(1);json_encode($arr);
```

In Ajax answer i have error 
****Fatal error**:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in **C:\xampp\htdocs\foo\1.php** on line **6****

Comment: It is performing an infinite loop and encoding the $arr, why are you doing this?

Comment: you should attach as string with JSON string data `echo "while(1);".json_encode($arr);`

Comment: @Girish yep, and the client which is making the request should strip the `while(1);` before parsing the JSON response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Girish very much 
works :

**1.php**

```
<?php
$time=time();
$hash=md5(mt_rand(1,200000));

$arr = array('time' => $time, 'hash' => $hash);
echo "while(1);".json_encode($arr);
```

**ajax -side**

```
responseText=req.responseText.substring(9);
            var obj=JSON.parse(responseText);

            statusElem.innerHTML = obj.hash
```