# how to change the encoding format of text file from Unicode to UTF-8

Tags: macros, vbscript

```
Dim txtFile, fileObj, streamObj, s

Set txtFile = CreateObject(fileName)

Set streamObj = CreatreObject("adodb.Stream")
streamObj.Charset = "UTF-8"
streamObj.open
Set fileObj = txtFile.OpenTextFile("filePath")

Do Until fileObj.AtEndOfStream
      s = fileObj.ReadLine
      txtObj.WriteText s
Loop

txtObj.SaveToFile "D:\A4\Message_tool\surya.msg", 2
fileObj.Close
```

After the execution this code the encoding format of surya.msg is "ANSCII" but I want it to be "UTF-8"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Dim inputFile, outputFile
    inputFile = "input_file.txt"
    outputFile = "output_file.txt"

Dim inputStream
    Set inputStream  = WScript.CreateObject("adodb.stream")
    With inputStream
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "unicode"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile inputFile
    End With

Dim outputStream
    Set outputStream = WScript.CreateObject("adodb.stream")
    With outputStream
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText inputStream.ReadText
        .SaveToFile outputFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    End With

    inputStream.Close
    outputStream.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Unicode-encoded text files can be opened in the usual way using the `OpenTextFile()` method of the `FileSystemObject` class. Just pass `True`/`-1` for the 4th ("format") parameter.

```
strText = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inputFile, , , True).ReadAll()
```

To encode your text as UTF-8, you'll need to use the `ADO Stream` class.

```
Const adTypeText = 2
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Type = adTypeText
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .WriteText strText
    .SaveToFile "D:\A4\Message_tool\surya.msg", adSaveCreateOverWrite 
End With
```

For a list of character encodings supported by Windows, look within the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Charset
```

Comment: The fourth/format parameter of the .OpenTextFile method takes a TriState, not a Boolean value.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Yep. But you can just use `True` for Unicode or `False` for ASCII to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @Bond - maybe you *can*, but you shouldn't. Furthermore you shouldn't insist on bad practices againt better knowledge: -1.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner LOL, whatever. Programmers having been taking advantage of `True = -1` and `False = 0` for longer than I've been around. I guess everyone who ever wrote a `while(1)` loop in C++ was "insisting on bad practices".

Comment: @Bond - Your guess is correct, because an endless loop in C++ is to be expressed as `while(true)` or `for(;;)`. `while(1)` is good C89/90, but made obsolete by the introduction of a boolean datatype in the C99 standard.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner And some of the best programmers still use the technique [even today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses).