# Symfony storing results of foreach loop

Tags: php, symfony

I'm wondering if is it possible to store results of foreach loop.
I dont know how to explain my question more detailed.

So lets say following gets me 3 different arrays

```
$events = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:Events')->findBy(array('event' => $eventId));
```

***`#name,color#`***

**1.  Party, pink

2.  Poolparty, blue

3. B-day, red**

and  `foreach` `$events` to avoid non-object call.

```
foreach($events as $e)
{
    $name = $e->getName();
    $color = $e->getColor();
}
```

Now I could just return array to twig and for loop them, but can I store them into arrays in controller?

**My current code**

```
$events = 
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestBundle:Events')->findBy(array('event' => $eventId));

foreach($events as $e)
{                   
    $name = $e->getName();
    $color = $e->getColor();

    $array = array(array("$name", "$color"));
}

return new JsonResponse($array);
```

With this I get only last array. In this case **B-day, red.** Hopefully someone can help me out with my question. Thanks for time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the result outside of the loop for it to be persisted between iterations. Depending on what you want, it would look like:

```
$output = array();

foreach($events as $event)
{
    $output[$event->getName()] = $event->getColor();
}

return new JsonResponse($output);
```

...or like this...

```
$output = array();

foreach($events as $event)
{
    $output[] = array($event->getName(), $event->getColor());
}

return new JsonResponse($output);
```

The output of the former looks like `{"B-day": "red", ...}` while the latter looks like `[["B-day", "red"], ...]`.

---

You would normally pick the former output because it is recommended that the outermost type in JSON used for AJAX be an object, not an array ([for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)).

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, it looks like you're building a json API of some sort. If that's true, I'd highly recommend using something like [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) to do this type of entity >> api conversion.