# symfony Response with json ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, model-view-controller

I'm new in Symfony i wanted to do some manipulation such  I can get a list of all elemets in the entity Theme via Ajax but the answer is still "undefined" Here the code text strong

**vue**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $theme = $('#theme');
        $theme.append('<option value="">Choisir un thème</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{ path('web_site_liste_theme_cmb') }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#themediv').append('<div id="loading" style=" float: left; display: block;"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/BackBundle/img/loadingicon.gif') }}"/></div>');
            },
            success: function (json) {
                {#$('#theme').append({{  dump(json)}});#}
                console.log(json.value);
                $.each(json, function (index, value) {

                    //console.log(value);
                    $('#theme').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
                    $('#loading').remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
  public function ListeThemeAction(Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $themes = $em->getRepository('WebSiteBackBundle:theme');
        $themes = $themes->findAll();
        //var_dump($themes);

        return  new JsonResponse($json);
    }
    return new JsonResponse('no results found', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND); // constant for 404

}
```

the server response is 200 OK, everything seems to work, I have the same number of data in the database but I can't read the objects values

and here is the :
[console.log(json)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydbA9.png)

Comment: can you provide some move info? what is the response from the server? what is 'undefined'? the "json.value"?

Comment: the server response is 200 OK, everything seems to work, I have the same number of data in the database but I do not read the objects values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, i found the answer i had to  change the controller to make it happen. 
thank you Yonel !
here is a link that helped me [Json in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924773/symfony-storing-results-of-foreach-loop)

**Controller**

```
public function ListeThemeAction(Request $request)
{
$output=array();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $themes = $em->getRepository('WebSiteBackBundle:theme');
        $themes = $themes->findAll();
        foreach ($themes as $theme){

            $output[]=array($theme->getId(),$theme->getName());
        }
     /*   var_dump($themes);
        $json = json_encode($themes);

        $response = new Response();*/
        //            return $response->setContent($json);
        return new JsonResponse($output);

    }
    return new JsonResponse('no results found', Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

**Vue**

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var $theme = $('#theme');
        $theme.append('<option value="">Choisir un thème</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{ path('web_site_liste_theme_cmb') }}',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#themediv').append('<div id="loading" style=" float: left; display: block;"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/BackBundle/img/loadingicon.gif') }}"/></div>');
            },
            success: function (json) {

                console.log(json);
                $.each(json, function (index, value) {

                    //console.log(value);
                    $('#theme').append('<option value="' + value[0]+ '">' + value[1] + '</option>');
                    $('#loading').remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Hoping it will help someone. thank you all for your answer it helped me a lot

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do that; I will show you one of them.

First, prepare your data to send it from a controller and return a `JsonResponse` instance:

```php
public function fooAction()
{
    $data = ['foo1' => 'bar1', 'foo2' => 'bar2'];

    return new JsonResponse($data); // or $this->json($data) since Symfony 3.1
}
```

> The `JsonResponse` tells the browser that the data sent must be interpreted as JSON; otherwise, these data are interpreted as plain text by default.

Second, use the same data structure for accessing it through a JavaScript callback function:

```js
$.post('{{ path('web_site_liste_theme_cmb') }}', function (data) {
    console.log(data['foo1']); // output: bar1
    console.log(data.foo2);    // output: bar2 
});
```

In your question, your data sent was an array of objects, so you need to look at this variable "json" (array) and access each property of the object.

Comment: how can i loop to each  property of object. i guess that i already did it in the " $.each(json, function (index, value) { ..." is that right ?

Comment: Yes, but it depends of your `WebSiteBackBundle:Theme` entity, if it contains the "id" and "value" properties. Otherwise, you should prepare these data before send the json response in your controller.