# Why do browsers execute <script> with content-type json?

Tags: javascript, json, security, content-type

Some webservers prepend JSON responses with a `while(1);`, e. g. `while(1);['id',123]`.

This is to prevent [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/):

> This is to ensure some other site can't do nasty tricks to try to
>   steal your data. For example, by replacing the array constructor, then
>   including this JSON URL via a  tag, a malicious third-party
>   site could steal the data from the JSON response. By putting a
>   while(1); at the start, the script will hang instead. @bdonlan, https://stackoverflow.com/a/871508/1647737

However, this 'misuse' of JSON content as a `<script>` source is only possible because webbrowsers (e. g. Firefox) execute scripts with content type `application/json`:

```html
<!-- Content-type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1 -->
<script src="http://code.jsontest.com/?mine=1"></script>
```

Can't browsers simply ignore remote scripts whose content type doesn't match? E. g. in above example, the [script type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) would be `application/javascript` (by default), but the respone has content type `application/json`. Why is it still executed as JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers tend to be VERY forgiving of `content-type`.  When JavaScript first showed up, there was no standardized `content-type` for it.

The upshot of this is that many older web servers send out JavaScript with a variety of content types and browsers pretty much accepted anything.  If a browser requested JavaScript, it assumed it got JavaScript back and executed it.

(It is even possible to hide JavaScript inside of a `GIF` and have it execute. Once reference: http://iamajin.blogspot.com/2014/11/when-gifs-serve-javascript.html)

Since the number one rule of web infrastructure is "*Don't break the Web*," nobody is willing to change the security model of scripts, and thus other work-arounds must be put into place.

In other words -- someone out there is serving regular JSON as JSONP and if a browser refused to execute it, the world would see the browser as being broken -- not the web server.

(Thank you  Quentin for the reference link and establishing a timeline for me.)