# Is there a proper way to parse JSON prepended with a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I know I can use jQuery and other libraries to easily handle this, but I'd like to know personally the best way to handle these responses. I've spent extensive time searching for the proper way to handle them, but all I find is the same explanations for why they exist: anti-hijacking.

So, the title speaks for itself. I know a very common implementation utilizes the prepending of a `while` loop, which could be dealt with using `.replace(/^while\(\d*\);/, '')`, but this feels like a crude and hackish way to handle it and it only accounts for one possible variation.

Is there a better way to handle it?

Trying to keep it simple, an example of this would be:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
});
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.json");
oReq.send();
```

This might produce a response like:

```
while(1);{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]}}}
```

Comment: How would you use jQuery?

Comment: Well, you could match `/\{.*\}$/` and then do a JSON.parse() on whatever that returns. That will work as long as your JSON is an object, and your "anti-hijacking" string doesn't contain any braces. Exchange braces for brackets `[]` in the regex for array JSON data

Comment: No, jQuery or other libraries *don't* handle this either.

Comment: Only way around it is to check for each "protection" and remove it. There is not going to be a one size fits all solution.

Comment: If I use `$.ajax({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://www.example.org/example.json', success: function(responseText) { console.log(responseText); }})` to make the same call, it parses the response without my having to do anything. In pure-JavaScript, I have to manually strip the loop before I can parse it.

Comment: I stand corrected. I found out that where I was using it has a custom modification to their jQuery installation that strips it. Mystery solved. Thank you to everyone that responded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this feels like a crude and hackish way to handle it and it only accounts for one possible variation.

No, it's exactly what you would do. Or even less generic, `.slice(9)`. Servers don't prepend arbitrary or even dynamically generated loops, they use the shortest/simplest possible one [to prevent JSON hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690/1048572). So you have to deal only with that particular prefix used by the service your are requesting.

Comment: Technically, the shortest loop would be `for(;;)`

Comment: That's what I figured was the case, but I wanted to ask, in case I was missing something and there was a "better" way to do it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `replace()`, another way could be using `slice()` out first 9 characters because `while(1);` has **9** characters, so you can discard it and use `JSON.parse()` to make it object from string.

```js
const js_string = 'while(1);{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]}}}';
//while(9); has 9 characters so remove it and parse it to json object
console.log(JSON.parse(js_string.slice(9)));
```