# How do I load JSON and split response string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a url that returns JSON, but the beginning of the return string is

`])}while(1);</x>{"success":true,"payload":{"value":`

I want to split on `])}while(1);</x>` and look at the [1] value of the that `split` array.

Right now I'm doing

```
fetch(jsonURL)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res); 
  });
```

Normally I'd split at the `console.log` but I'm getting the following error:

> the-myth-of-the-genius-programmer-9381a884591e:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 0

Comment: If that's what it's returning, it's not JSON.

Comment: Why don't you fix the server code to return proper JSON?

Comment: That looks vaguely like a XSSI-prefix, but what follows after the prefix is not remotely valid JSON.

Comment: this not a correct fetch

Comment: @Amy Why isn't it valid JSON? He said it's just the beginning, that's why it's not properly balanced.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses before attempting to fix it server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `response.text()` to get the raw text of the response, so you can remove the extraneous stuff at the beginning. Then you have to parse the JSON yourself, you can't use `res.json()`.

```
fetch(jsonURL)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => {
    text = text.replace('])}while(1);</x>', '');
    let obj = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(obj);
|);
```

This assumes the extraneous stuff is only at the beginning. If there's also something after the JSON, you'll need to remove that as well.