# Why does GitHub prepend this string to <form> opening tags?

Tags: html, security

The string in question is:

```
<!-- '"` --><!-- </textarea></xmp> --></option></form>
```

The two last closing tags are stray (i.e. don't correspond to any opening tags). [This makes the markup invalid](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2F), but browsers don't care. The string appears before every `<form>` opening tag.

Is this done to prevent some attack, like [`while(1);` was used to prevent JSON hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690/9253414)?

**Note:** It seems this question was asked before in [another now-removed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62022632/9253414). I can't see the question and I don't know why it was removed.

Comment: the question you link to doesn't have any answer or useful information so you aren't missing out.