# What are the leading signs ")]}'" in recaptcha response

Tags: json, response, recaptcha

I am setting up recaptcha v2 and was checking out the recaptcha response morde detailed. 
There I recognized, that every response from google itself, is leaded by these strange signs, never mind if visible, invisible or programatically executed.

`)]}'`

followed by something like this

`["uvresp","03AGdBq27hrqX5c9NoijbtFp-MCEjFB7ypsgHF-qMh5A0Kh7f3SS_GCFb1LRAj94hzram5sCMkLc8XhXyQ-r8QygJqrE0FE07xc-qjLspslswX06GtG2nY2e9cnW1pVOnc1D1bNqqN1qnPZNuciwClycThkKmoVrPQeXMr3FyGPEcbVgu8mz25bvKP538s5xBhaf3kjAc2WA4Lv3KULdPdZL9MD5fJQnt17xXbJxLmDoDUBgCOqXw7FHFPMtcp7cP2cO0fCTq_kAG6okXPJxH0IlFXV7aPSt2idGYDINuJWT53tA48RF_NWxYezb13qyPvxcjfCky2i0Yr7QVQn5b_yKAzOZN0btdt4H0g3Fzmg4u0SJefuZOgbVqJSXIWECZrp6OsnsNIAQrtVdd97vn5gD4Grbxt-IlhbrF1ChKkV5Vay9Ha24gmXnw",1,120]`

According to the header, the response type is `application/json; charset=utf-8`.
So the second part is a valid json, but the first part I don't know what it is and why the browser is not complaining about an invalid json.

Can someone help me out and explain it to me?

Comment: I've read something along the lines of it being a protection about injections of some sort, but I'm still searching for the relevant source. But at least it's purposely generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)