# What does the `)]}'` at the top of this JSON response do?

Tags: json, parsing

I notice that the JSON returned from https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id has the characters `)]}'` at the top of the response, rendering the resulting data unparseable by `JSON.parse()`, or any other typical JSON parser. Since it consists entirely of random punctuation, I've been unable to coax any of the usual search engines into telling me anything about this strange pattern.

Is that practice documented somewhere? What's its purpose?

**Complete example**

```
)]}'

{"id":"ANyPxKoB8RXojXE04wzPs6XPWLf8jfwTIIz7z5yP0Nty0okYZoyQVdoZN1SubUUvrugz00VCshNAGs4KV15j419hQey1el_7Ow"}
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63961703/2557263

Comment: Probably the same as [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)