# How to get all elements as rows for each href in HTML and add it to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to fetch as rows the different values inside each href element from the following website: https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/mercados/capitales

There should be 1 row that matches each field on the provided headers for each different `href` element on the HTML file.

This is one of the portions of the HTML that I am trying to scrape:

```
  <tbody>
    
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="sorting_1"><a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/1959">AC
  
</a></td><td><span class="series">*</span>
</td><td>03:20</td><td><span class="color-2">191.04

</span></td><td>191.32</td>
<td>194.51</td>
<td>193.92</td>
<td>191.01</td>
<td>380,544</td>
<td>73,122,008.42</td>
<td>2,793</td>
<td>-3.19</td><td>-1.64</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even">
  <td class="sorting_1"><a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/203">ACCELSA</a>
  </td>
  <td><span class="series">B</span>
  </td><td>03:20</td><td>
    <span class="">22.5</span></td><td>0</td>
    <td>22.5</td><td>0</td><td>0

    </td><td>3</td><td>67.20</td>
    <td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">
        <a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/6096">ACTINVR</a></td>
      <td><span class="series">B</span></td><td>03:20</td><td>
        <span class="">15.13</span></td><td>0</td><td>15.13</td><td>0</td>
        <td>0</td><td>13</td><td>196.69</td><td>4</td><td>0</td>
        <td>0</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">
          <a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/339083">AGUA</a></td>
          <td><span class="series">*</span>
          </td><td>03:20</td><td>
            <span class="color-1">29</span>
          </td><td>28.98</td><td>28.09</td>
            <td>29</td><td>28</td><td>296,871</td>
            <td>8,491,144.74</td><td>2,104</td><td>0.89</td>
            <td>3.17</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">
              <a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/30">ALFA</a></td><td><span class="series">A</span></td>
              <td>03:20</td>
              <td><span class="color-2">13.48</span>
              </td><td>13.46</td>
              <td>13.53</td><td>13.62</td><td>13.32</td>
              <td>2,706,398</td>
              td>36,494,913.42</td><td>7,206</td><td>-0.07</td>
              <td>-0.52</td>
            </tr><tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">
              <a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/7684">ALPEK</a></td><td><span class="series">A</span>
              </td><td>03:20</td><td><span class="color-2">10.65</span>
            </td><td>10.64</td><td>10.98</td><td>10.88</td><td>10.53</td>
            <td>1,284,847</td><td>13,729,368.46</td><td>6,025</td><td>-0.34</td>
            <td>-3.10</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">
              <a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/1729">ALSEA</a></td><td><span class="series">*</span>
            </td><td>03:20</td><td><span class="color-2">65.08</span></td><td>64.94</td><td>65.44</td><td>66.78</td><td>64.66</td><td>588,826</td><td>38,519,244.51</td><td>4,442</td><td>-0.5</td><td>-0.76</td></tr>
            <tr role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">
              <a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/424518">ALTERNA</a></td><td><span class="series">B</span></td><td>03:20</td><td><span class="">1.5</span></td><td>0</td><td>1.5</td>
              <td>0</td><td>0</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">
              <a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/1862">AMX</a></td>
              <td><span class="series">B</span></td><td>03:20</td>
              <td><span class="color-2">14.56</span></td><td>14.58</td>
              <td>14.69</td><td>14.68</td><td>14.5</td><td>86,023,759</td>
              <td>1,254,412,623.59</td><td>41,913</td><td>-0.11</td>
              <td>-0.75</td></tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                <td class="sorting_1"><a href="/es/mercados/cotizacion/6507">ANGELD</a>
              </td><td><span class="series">10</span></td><td>03:20</td><td>
                <span class="color-2">21.09</span>
              </td><td>21.1</td><td>21.44</td><td>21.23</td><td>21.09</td>
              <td>51,005</td><td>1,076,281.67</td>
              <td>22</td><td>-0.34</td><td>-1.59</td></tr>
      </tbody>
```

And my current code results into an empty `dataframe`:

```
# create empty pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# get response code from webhost
page = requests.get('https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/mercados/capitales')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
#print(soup.p.text)
# yet it doesn't bring the expected rows!

print('Read html!')

# get headers

tbody = soup.find("thead")
tr = tbody.find_all("tr")

headers= [t.get_text().strip().replace('\n', ',').split(',') for t in tr][0]

#print(headers)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

# fetch rows into pandas dataframe# You can find children with multiple tags by passing a list of strings
rows = soup.find_all('tr', {"role":"row"})
#rows

for row in rows:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    for cell in cells:
        value = cell.string

        #print("The value in this cell is %s" % value)

        # append row in dataframe
```

I would like to know if it's possible to get a `pandas` dataframe whose fields are the ones portrayed in the headers list and the rows are each element from href.

For better perspective, the expected output should be equal to the table at the bottom of the provided website. Whose first row has the next schema:

```
EMISORA SERIE   HORA    ÚLTIMO   PPP    ANTERIOR    MÁXIMO  MÍNIMO VOLUMEN  IMPORTE OPS.    VAR PUNTOS  VAR %
AC        *    3:20    191.04   191.32  194.51     193.92   191.01  380,544  73,122,008.42   2,793  -3.19    -1.64
```

Is this possible to create such dataset?

Comment: If the webpage has html tables, look at using `pd.read_html`.

Comment: Also, the expected output is unclear, please provide an exact output matching the given input.

Comment: Hey, I've provided the details about the expected dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned before, the table is loaded and rendered dynamically via JavaScript, something you could not handle with `requests` because it just get the static response and does not behave like a browser.

A solution to mimic a browsers behaviour is given by @thetaco using `selenium` but you could get your goal also with `requests` while using the source the data comes from.

1. Get the request url use your [browsers dev tools to inspect the network traffic](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network) in this example it is: https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/Grupo_BMV/BmvJsonGeneric?idSitioPagina=4
2. Extract the string from the response (it is not valid JSON)

   ```
   requests.get('https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/Grupo_BMV/BmvJsonGeneric?idSitioPagina=4').text.split(';(', 1)[-1].split(')')[0]
   ```
3. Convert the string into JSON (`json.loads()`) and tranform it with `pandas.json_normalize()` into a dataframe. Your data is under the path `['response']['resultado']['A']`
4. The column names may differ a bit because they are build on the keyes from the JSON but they could be easily mapped.

The response contains all content, including that of the other groups (`ACCIONES, CKD'S, FIBRAS, TÍTULOS OPCIONALES`) which can also be extracted (`A, CKDS, F, TO`) would be the abbreviations that can be used analogously for the selection.

###### Example (all available information for ACCIONES from XHR Request)

```
import json, requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(
    json.loads(
        requests.get('https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/Grupo_BMV/BmvJsonGeneric?idSitioPagina=4')\
            .text\
            .split(';(', 1)[-1]\   
            .split(')')[0]
        )['response']['resultado']['A']
)\
.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

|  | idEmision | idTpvalor | cveSerie | cveCorta | idEmisora | datosEstadistica.hora | datosEstadistica.maximo | datosEstadistica.minimo | datosEstadistica.importeAcomulado | datosEstadistica.noOperaciones | datosEstadistica.variacionPuntos | datosEstadistica.variacionPorcentual | datosEstadistica.precioUltimoHecho | datosEstadistica.ppp | datosEstadistica.precioAnterior | datosEstadistica.volumenOperado | datosEstadistica.anioEjercicio | datosEstadistica.insumosPu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1959 | 1 | * | AC | 6081 | 03:20 | 192.98 | 189.01 | 9.54831e+07 | 3333 | -2.59 | -1.35 | 189.3 | 189.32 | 191.91 | 502297 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 203 | 1 | B | ACCELSA | 5015 | 03:20 | 0 | 0 | 22.4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 22.5 | 0 | 22.5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 103 | 404833 | 1B | 19 | VMEX | 34347 | 03:20 | 45.29 | 45.29 | 11007.9 | 8 | 0.14 | 0.31 | 45.29 | 0 | 45.15 | 243 | 0 | 0 |
| 104 | 327336 | 1 | A | VOLAR | 30023 | 03:20 | 12.76 | 12.42 | 1.5744e+07 | 5006 | 0.24 | 1.93 | 12.67 | 12.68 | 12.44 | 1246397 | 0 | 0 |
| 105 | 5 | 1 | * | WALMEX | 5214 | 03:20 | 70.37 | 67.83 | 1.21326e+09 | 19593 | -2.02 | -2.86 | 68.7 | 68.72 | 70.74 | 17639588 | 0 | 0 |

---

Coming closer to your result, you could post process the `dataframe` to your needs:

```
import re
# exclude all columns referencing an id information
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('id')]
# adjust the column names
df.columns = [re.sub(r"(?<=\w)([A-Z])", r" \1", c).split('.')[-1].lstrip('cve').upper() for c in df.columns]
df
```

| SERIE | CORTA | HORA | MAXIMO | MINIMO | IMPORTE ACOMULADO | NO OPERACIONES | ARIACION PUNTOS | ARIACION PORCENTUAL | PRECIO ULTIMO HECHO | PPP | PRECIO ANTERIOR | OLUMEN OPERADO | ANIO EJERCICIO | INSUMOS PU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| * | AC | 03:20 | 191.17 | 187.8 | 1.14863e+08 | 4175 | 0.64 | 0.34 | 189.65 | 189.96 | 189.32 | 604632 | 0 | 0 |
| B | ACTINVR | 03:20 | 15.03 | 15.03 | 36614.4 | 14 | 0 | 0 | 15.03 | 0 | 15.03 | 2436 | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| A | VOLAR | 03:20 | 12.97 | 12.51 | 1.48613e+07 | 2832 | 0.07 | 0.55 | 12.83 | 12.75 | 12.68 | 1162684 | 0 | 0 |
| * | WALMEX | 03:20 | 69.03 | 67.66 | 7.2698e+08 | 22462 | -0.71 | -1.03 | 68 | 68.01 | 68.72 | 10672270 | 0 | 0 |

or simply map against the columns, to get exact column names:

```
map_dict = {'cveSerie':'SERIE', 'cveCorta':'EMISORA', 'datosEstadistica.hora':'HORA', 'datosEstadistica.maximo':'MÁXIMO',
       'datosEstadistica.minimo':'MÍNIMO', 'datosEstadistica.importeAcomulado':'IMPORTE', 'datosEstadistica.noOperaciones':'OPS.', 'datosEstadistica.variacionPuntos':'VAR PUNTOS',
       'datosEstadistica.variacionPorcentual':'VAR %', 'datosEstadistica.precioUltimoHecho':'ÚLTIMO', 'datosEstadistica.ppp':'PPP',
       'datosEstadistica.precioAnterior':'ANTERIOR', 'datosEstadistica.volumenOperado':'VOLUMEN'}
df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c in map_dict.keys()]].rename(columns=map_dict)
```

| SERIE | EMISORA | HORA | MÁXIMO | MÍNIMO | IMPORTE | OPS. | VAR PUNTOS | VAR % | ÚLTIMO | PPP | ANTERIOR | VOLUMEN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| * | AC | 03:20 | 191.17 | 187.8 | 1.14863e+08 | 4175 | 0.64 | 0.34 | 189.65 | 189.96 | 189.32 | 604632 |

...

Answer (score 3):

The website you provided uses Javascript to load content dynamically, meaning `Beautifulsoup` will receive HTML in its response, but will be missing significant pieces. For this reason, you will have to integrate your `Beautifulsoup` code with a more sophisticated tool like `Selenium`.

Most of your code is correct, but is working with only a subset of the data that is shown on the page due to dynamic rendering. I have adjusted your code to include `Selenium` code; this will navigate to the website, wait for the Javascript to load, scrape the newly-rendered data, and make the table into a Pandas dataframe:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/mercados/capitales'

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(4) # wait for page to load

html_content = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', id='tableMercados')

#get column names
columns = [th.get_text().strip() for th in table.find_all('th')]
data = []
rows = table.find('tbody').find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    row_data = [col.get_text().strip() for col in row.find_all('td')]
    data.append(row_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

Printing the Dataframe shows the following data:

```
   EMISORA SERIE   HORA ÚLTIMO     PPP ANTERIOR  MÁXIMO  MÍNIMO     VOLUMEN           IMPORTE    OPS. VAR PUNTOS  VAR %
0       AC     *  03:20  189.3  189.32   191.91  192.98  189.01     502,297     95,483,093.50   3,333      -2.59  -1.35
1  ACCELSA     B  03:20   22.5       0     22.5       0       0           1             22.40       1          0      0
2  ACTINVR     B  03:20  15.03       0       15   15.06   15.03      55,479        833,864.22      22       0.03   0.20
3     AGUA     *  03:20  31.55   31.59     30.2   31.98    29.8     327,380     10,149,130.38   2,283       1.39   4.60
4  ALEATIC     *  03:20   36.5       0     36.5       0       0           7            254.50       2          0      0
5     ALFA     A  03:20  13.19   13.19    13.04    13.4   13.01   4,045,917     53,405,549.08  11,798       0.15   1.15
6    ALPEK     A  03:20  10.84   10.82    10.73   10.93   10.67     369,472      3,999,136.42   4,451       0.09   0.84
7    ALSEA     *  03:20  66.75   66.55    64.98   66.98   65.12   5,939,525    390,969,784.88   3,995       1.57   2.42
8  ALTERNA     B  03:20    1.5       0      1.5       0       0          50             77.50       2          0      0
9      AMX     B  03:20  15.27   15.29    15.01   15.38   15.01  96,328,174  1,472,868,239.86  48,894       0.28   1.87
```

Which matches the data on the website:

[image]

**EDIT:**
If you wish to scrape all of the data that the website provides, you will need to click the "next" button using `Selenium`. Here is an example doing just that; `Beautifulsoup` unfortunately does not provide the ability to click buttons.

(NOTE: sometimes you can scrape different url's to solve this issue if clicking "next" loads a different url, but clicking "next" on this page renders new data with Javascript instead of changing the url, meaning `Selenium` is doubly needed)

Here is the Selenium code to scrape all data provided by the site:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/mercados/capitales'
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # 10 second timeout
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tableMercados_next")))

all_data = []

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    
    if not all_data:
        table = soup.find('table', id='tableMercados')
        columns = [th.get_text().strip() for th in table.find_all('th')]
    
    rows = table.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        row_data = [col.get_text().strip() for col in row.find_all('td')]
        all_data.append(row_data)

    # checks if there is a next page; element is disabled if there isnt
    next_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "tableMercados_next")
    if "disabled" in next_button.get_attribute("class"):
        print("Reached the last page.")
        break 
    # load next page
    next_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)

# create df from data
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=columns)
driver.quit()
print(df)
```

This will provide the following dataframe, with 110 rows. There are 10 rows per page and 11 pages:

[image]

**EDIT 2**:
If you do not have `Selenium` installed, you can install it according to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) documentation as follows:

1. `pip install -U selenium`
2. Install a Driver; I use the Chromedriver that can be found [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Answer (score 2):

***In an earlier version of the answer, I described a method to directly access the desired data. However, I recommend reaching out to the website and request direct access to the data through their XML web service.***

---

Apparently, the website makes an XHR request to a URL, then displays the data in a pageable grid (BeautifulSoup cannot *see* this JavaScript generated content). You can find that URL by looking at Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab > Fetch/XHR.

The response consists of JSON, [JSON hijacking protection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690/87015) and some HTML comments. Once you remove the two unwanted parts, you get valid JSON. Below is a subset of that JSON:

```
{
  "errorsCode": [],
  "response": {
    "resultado": {
      "CKDS": [],
      "F": [
        {
          "idEmision": 328070,
          "idTpvalor": "CF",
          "cveSerie": "13",
          "cveCorta": "DANHOS",
          "datosEstadistica": {
            "hora": "03:20",
            "maximo": "20.96",
            "minimo": "20.71",
            "importeAcomulado": 4212438.49,
            "noOperaciones": 1876,
            "variacionPuntos": -0.01,
            "variacionPorcentual": -0.05,
            "precioUltimoHecho": 20.71,
            "ppp": 20.74,
            "precioAnterior": 20.75,
            "volumenOperado": 202746,
            "anioEjercicio": 0,
            "insumosPu": 0
          },
          "idEmisora": 31300
        }
      ]
    },
    "url": "/es/mercados/cotizacion/"
  },
  "success": true
}
```

Downloading contents from a URL and parsing it as JSON is trivial. You will have all the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

The polite thing to do is to `GET` the dataset directly. It doesn't change where in the gray you land on the legal side, means less work for the server, and results in less data being sent around pointlessly.

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

# TODO: I would translate these to english
name_mapping = {
    'cveCorta': 'EMISORA',
    'cveSerie': 'SERIE',
    'datosEstadistica.hora': 'HORA',
    'datosEstadistica.precioUltimoHecho': 'ÚLTIMO',
    'datosEstadistica.ppp': 'PPP',
    'datosEstadistica.precioAnterior': 'ANTERIOR',
    'datosEstadistica.maximo': 'MAXIMO',
    'datosEstadistica.minimo': 'MINIMO',
    'datosEstadistica.volumenOperado': 'VOLUMEN',
    'datosEstadistica.importeAcomulado': 'IMPORTE_OPS',
    'datosEstadistica.variacionPuntos': 'VAR_PUNTOS',
    'datosEstadistica.variacionPorcentual': 'VAR_%',
}

result = requests.get("https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/Grupo_BMV/BmvJsonGeneric?idSitioPagina=4")
start, end = result.text.find("{"), result.text.rfind("}") + 1
raw_data = json.loads(result.text[start:end])["response"]["resultado"]

data = (
    pd.json_normalize(raw_data["F"] + raw_data["A"])
    .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
    .rename(columns=name_mapping)
    .loc[:, name_mapping.values()]
    .sort_values("EMISORA")
)

#TODO: persist/cache the data to reduce server-side load
```

The *method* aside, it is worth noting that you should be mindful of IP (intellectual property) and ToS (Terms of Service) when writing automation like this. What is or isn't allowed will depend on your country, the website's country, the collected data, and a couple other things. When in doubt, ask a legal professional what restrictions apply to your case.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML and extract the necessary information from the `href` attributes. Then, construct a pandas DataFrame using this information.

Try this:

```py
# Find all rows
rows = soup.find_all('tr')

# Iterate over each row
for row in rows:
    # Find the anchor tag within the row
    anchor = row.find('a')
    if anchor:
        # Extract href and text content
        href = anchor['href']
        text = anchor.text.strip()
        
        # Find all cells in the row
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        # Extract other cell values
        cell_values = [cell.text.strip() for cell in cells]
        
        # Combine all values into a single row
        row_data = [text, *cell_values]
        
        # Append the row data to the main data list
        data.append(row_data)

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
```

Comment: is it possible to apply this to the following website: https://www.bmv.com.mx/es/mercados/capitales ? ... I am trying to fetch the table at the bottom of the website