# What does while(1) in Gmail do

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why have “while(1);” in XmlHttpRequest response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871505/why-have-while1-in-xmlhttprequest-response)

If you take a peek at the XHR POST requests that Gmail makes to the server when it updates the list of your email, you will see that each response starts with:

```
while(1);

[[["v","CKbPYpt__Vc.en.","8","d7634f09ff9e61c8"]
,["di",342]
,["ub",[["^i",1296218266987]
,["^f",1296218266987]
(...)
```

Why does Google start each response with endless loop?

I read that it is a security trick http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/show.dml/260127 but I am not sure how it is supposed to be a good security measure.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871505/why-have-while1-in-xmlhttprequest-response

Comment: You are right, search engine did not show it to me when I searched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a guess... So that any malicious attempt to `eval` the response or point a `<script>` block at the resource, rather than parsing it properly, will fail.

Comment: but I can simply remove "while(1) with string replace before eval, so no big difference

Comment: @warpech: But you can't (generally) do a cross-site XmlHttpRequest and then pre-parse before passing to `eval`. Pulling that response cross-site would require a `<script>` tag which would then result in the browser hanging when it hits the `while(1)`.

Comment: No, if you can't do a XHR request on this URL you will not be able to get the raw data.

Comment: I understand now... The way to understand this JSON response would be to put it into <script src=""> and overflow Array object