# What type is it, json gzip

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing

> **Possible duplicates**
>
> - [What does a Ajax call response like 'for (;;); { json data }' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099820/215042)
> - [Why do people put code like “throw 1; ” and “for(;;);” in front of json responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146798/why-do-people-put-code-like-throw-1-dont-be-evil-and-for-in-front-of)
> - [Why have “while(1);” in XmlHttpRequest response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871505/why-have-while1-in-xmlhttprequest-response)
> - [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses)

Im trying to parse a website  and one request returns such content:

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"domops":[["appendContent","^div.fbProfileBrowserListContainer",true,{"__html":"\u003Cdiv ... ]
```

Here is image :
[image]
What type is it gzip  or what?  I need  to parse  it from c#, but can't get response. Response is always empty or question marks. What parameter need to add in header request to read response. Can't figure it out.

Comment: How can i get it from httpwebrequest? Is it possible?

Comment: Simply remove it from the response (with a `replace` for example) before you pass the response to a Json parser.

Comment: Okey i got it, Now i need online parser for it to see actual content

Comment: I got the response correctly, but how to parse it and get specific information

Comment: Use [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx), [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) or any other method you prefer. Even a [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) like `^for \(;;\);` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```cs
//Get actual response from server; here we use a hardcoded response
var response = "for (;;);{\"__ar\":1,\"payload\":null,\"domops\"....";

var fixedresponse = response.Substring(9);
```

Or, alternatively:

```cs
var fixedresponse = new Regex(@"^for \(;;\);").Replace(response, string.Empty);
```

Or...

```cs
var fixedresponse = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("{"));
```

Or, alternatively (*but less 'safe'* since the actual JSON content may *also* contain an empty for-loop):

```cs
var fixedresponse = response.Replace("for (;;);", string.Empty);
```

...or any other string operation you can think of actually; whatever gets the job (removing the stuff before the actual JSON) done.

You can read the "possible duplicates" I editted in your question for an explanation on *why* the empty for-loop is there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it like this:

```
'for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,".....'.substr(9);
```

As one comment already stated out, this is to prevent code injection. Everything after the for loop seems to be valid json. So just use the output of the code above with your json parser.

Comment: It's C# so that would be `myresponse.Substring(9)` (capital S).

Comment: Oh yes sorry, thats true :) If you have any problems parsing json in c#, take a look at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json